# How to log python exception?

Tags: python, exception, logging, python-logging

How can I log an exception in Python?

I've looked at some options and found out I can access the actual exception details using this code:

```
import sys
import traceback

try:
    1/0
except:
    exc_type, exc_value, exc_traceback = sys.exc_info()
    traceback.print_exception(exc_type, exc_value, exc_traceback)
```

I would like to somehow get the string `print_exception()` throws to stdout so that I can log it.

Comment: At least `raise` (without argument, so the stracktrace gets preserved) after logging, otherwise you swallow the exception silently.

Comment: You should always explicitly state the exception you are trying to catch: `except NameError as e`, say. That will prevent you catching things like `KeyboardInterrupt` *and* give you a reference to the exception object, which you can study for more details.

Answer (score 102, accepted):

In Python 3.5 you can pass exception instance in exc_info argument:

```
import logging
try:
    1/0
except Exception as e:
   logging.error('Error at %s', 'division', exc_info=e)
```

Comment: This is exactly what I wanted. I needed to log an [exception from a task](https://docs.python.org/3/library/asyncio-task.html#asyncio.Task.exception) and didn't have an except block.

Comment: Or just directly use `logging.exception("..")` and it will automatically log the traceback.

Answer (score 162):

Take a look at `logging.exception` ([Python Logging Module](http://docs.python.org/library/logging.html))

```
import logging 
def foo():
    try:
        some_code()
    except:
        logging.exception('')
```

This should automatically take care of getting the traceback for the current exception and logging it properly.

Comment: `except` catch-all can be a bad idea: http://stackoverflow.com/a/4990739/1091116

Answer (score 64):

To answer your question, you can get the string version of `print_exception()` using the [`traceback.format_exception()`](http://docs.python.org/library/traceback.html#traceback.format_exception) function. It returns the traceback message as a list of strings rather than printing it to stdout, so you can do what you want with it. For example:

```
import sys
import traceback

try:
    asdf
except NameError:
    exc_type, exc_value, exc_traceback = sys.exc_info()
    lines = traceback.format_exception(exc_type, exc_value, exc_traceback)
    print ''.join('!! ' + line for line in lines)  # Log it or whatever here
```

This displays:

```
!! Traceback (most recent call last):
!!   File "<stdin>", line 2, in <module>
!! NameError: name 'asdf' is not defined
```

However, I'd definitely recommend using the standard Python logging module, as suggested by rlotun. It's not the easiest thing to set up, but it's very customizable.

Comment: "not the easiest thing to set up" sort of implies that it's *hard* to set up, but that's just not true, `logging.basicConfig()` in the main function is adequate for most simple applications.

Comment: You code is useful when you cannot use logging package. E.g. When implementing a logging Handler :-)

Comment: @Doomsday, I would think implementing a [`logging.Handler`](https://docs.python.org/library/logging.html#handler-objects) might be the only good use for this code. For the OP's original question, OP should definitely use [logging](http://docs.python.org/library/logging.html) with `logging.exception` or log at a lower level with `exc_info=True`.

Answer (score 62):

Logging exceptions is as simple as adding the exc_info=True keyword argument to any log message, see entry for Logger.debug in http://docs.python.org/2/library/logging.html.

Example:

```
try: 
    raise Exception('lala')
except Exception:
    logging.info('blah', exc_info=True)
```

output (depending, of course, on your log handler config):

```
2012-11-29 10:18:12,778 - root - INFO - <ipython-input-27-5af852892344> : 3 - blah
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "<ipython-input-27-5af852892344>", line 1, in <module>
    try: raise Exception('lala')
Exception: lala
```

Comment: You're going to a lot of effort.  Why not just `logging.exception(exc)`?

Comment: logging.exception is short for logging.error(..., exc_info=True), so if you intend to log the exception as an error it would be better to use logging.exception. If you want to log a formatted exception at a log level other than error you must use exc_info=True.

Comment: "explicit is better than implicit"

Comment: @ChrisJohnson - you could simply use logging.exception() in your example...

Also, there are perfectly reasonable architectural reasons to want to log exception info and not set the log's `LEVEL` to `ERROR`. `logger.exception` is a unique case since it's the only call that doesn't explicitly set the `LEVEL` to be its function name. `logger.exception()` sets the level to `ERROR`.

We have alarms tied to spikes in errors, and although some exceptions are not important enough to raise those alarms, we definitely want to log the exc_info for them.

Answer (score 2):

First of all, consider using a proper Exception type on your except clause.
Then, naming the exception, you can print it:

```
try:
    1/0
except Exception as e:
    print e
```

Dependending on your Python version, you must use

```
except Exception, e
```

Comment: Printing is not logging.  Use `logging.exception(exc)`.

Comment: @ChrisJohnson you've recommended `logging.exception(exc)` in a few comments on this page, but it's a bad idea. The first argument to `logging.exception` isn't for the exception to log (Python just grabs the one from the current `except:` block by magic), it's for the *message* to log before the traceback. Specifying the exception as the message causes it to be converted to a string, which results in the exception message being duplicated. If you don't have a meaningful message to log along with your exception, use `logging.exception('')`, but `logging.exception(exc)` makes little sense.

Comment: This is the most candid code here. Meaningful message as default.