# Catch any error in Python

Tags: python, exception, try-catch, fallback

Is it possible to catch *any* error in Python? I don't care what the specific exceptions will be, because all of them will have the same fallback.

Comment: And like the dog that chases cars down the country road: what will you do when you catch it?  Some errors (i.e. MemoryError) mean Python is already crashing.

Comment: @S.Lott Well I've used that in some long running applications to inform me of the problem if possible. Sure some errors will be grave enough that nothing will help (because you can't do anything any longer), but still it's better than nothing.

Comment: @Voo: "better than nothing"?  I find that it's usually worse than noting.  Out of Memory, for example, means things have *already* failed to operate properly.  Recovery of some valid "prior state" of the Python computation seems impossible.

Comment: Does this answer your question? [About catching ANY exception](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4990718/about-catching-any-exception)

Comment: maybe this is a better answer? https://stackoverflow.com/a/4992124/1601580 I like this comment in particular `The advantage of except Exception over the bare except is that there are a few exceptions that it wont catch, most obviously KeyboardInterrupt and SystemExit: if you caught and swallowed those then you could make it hard for anyone to exit your script.`

Answer (score 64, accepted):

Using `except` by itself will catch any exception short of a segfault.

```
try:
    something()
except:
    fallback()
```

You might want to handle KeyboardInterrupt separately in case you need to use it to exit your script:

```
try:
    something()
except KeyboardInterrupt:
    return
except:
    fallback()
```

There's a nice list of basic exceptions you can catch [here](http://docs.python.org/library/exceptions.html). I also quite like the [traceback](http://docs.python.org/library/traceback.html) module for retrieving a call stack from the exception. Try `traceback.format_exc()` or `traceback.print_exc()` in an exception handler.

Comment: In most cases, you should also let `NameError` (and perhaps a few others like `AttributeError`) propagate as they inidicate bugs in your code.

Comment: It's often better practice to catch `except Exception` - KeyboardInterrupt and SystemExit don't inherit from Exception, so you can still 'break out'. Depends on what you're doing it for, of course.

Comment: Where does `fallback()` come from? I receive "NameError: name 'fallback' is not defined"!

Comment: but I want to pointer to `e` the exception NO MATTER THE TYPE.

Comment: @Apostolos answerer. ;)

Comment: ... Now I am more confused, @Charlie ...  I shouldn't have asked! :))

Comment: @Apostolos sorry apostolos, you are right, my first comment is confusing. I should have been less careless. Let's fix it now with this comment. My need was that I want to be able to have a pointer to the actual exception. His `except:` doesn't allow that and other answers like `except Exception as e:` don't capture EVERYTHING. The reason I need everything is, if the HPC system I use interputs my script, I want to catch that and then send myself an email about it and then have my script exit safely.

Comment: @Charlie, I found this that might be of help: `except: print("Error:", sys.exc_info()[0])` (Re: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4990718/about-catching-any-exception). I didn't know it myself. So thanks for this exchange! But I just saw that the answer that follows is maybe more close to what you are looking for!

Comment: maybe this is a better answer? https://stackoverflow.com/a/4992124/1601580 I like this comment in particular `The advantage of except Exception over the bare except is that there are a few exceptions that it wont catch, most obviously KeyboardInterrupt and SystemExit: if you caught and swallowed those then you could make it hard for anyone to exit your script.`

Answer (score 51):

```
try:
    # do something
except Exception, e:
    # handle it
```

For Python 3.x:

```
try:
    # do something
except Exception as e:
    # handle it
```

Comment: how is this different from the accepted answer? I see the code is different but do you mind maybe adding some comments/details?

Comment: Exception will not catch all the errors,however except will.

Comment: I dont think this is proper syntax

Comment: @CharlieParker It's different because in this case you have access to an `Exception` object.

Comment: @sergzach so the first option captures ALL errors and gives me a pointer to the exception  object through `e`?`

Comment: @3pitt did you try it?

Comment: @CharlieParker Probably you have another Python version, so, it does not work. Try the second.

Comment: maybe this is a better answer? https://stackoverflow.com/a/4992124/1601580 I like this comment in particular `The advantage of except Exception over the bare except is that there are a few exceptions that it wont catch, most obviously KeyboardInterrupt and SystemExit: if you caught and swallowed those then you could make it hard for anyone to exit your script.`

Answer (score 16):

You might want also to look at [sys.excepthook](http://docs.python.org/library/sys.html#sys.excepthook):

> When an exception is raised and uncaught, the interpreter calls
>   sys.excepthook with three arguments, the exception class, exception
>   instance, and a traceback object. In an interactive session this
>   happens just before control is returned to the prompt; in a Python
>   program this happens just before the program exits. The handling of
>   such top-level exceptions can be customized by assigning another
>   three-argument function to sys.excepthook.

Example:

```
def except_hook(type, value, tback):
    # manage unhandled exception here
    sys.__excepthook__(type, value, tback) # then call the default handler

sys.excepthook = except_hook
```

Comment: but I want to pointer to `e` the exception NO MATTER THE TYPE.

Answer (score 12):

Quoting the bounty text:

> I want to be able to capture ANY exception even weird ones like
> keyboard interrupt or even system exit (e.g. if my HPC manger throws
> an error) and get a handle to the exception object e, whatever it
> might be. I want to process e and custom print it or even send it by
> email

Look at the [exception hierarchy](https://docs.python.org/3/library/exceptions.html#exception-hierarchy), you need to catch `BaseException`:

```
BaseException
 +-- SystemExit
 +-- KeyboardInterrupt
 +-- GeneratorExit
 +-- Exception
```

This will capture `KeyboardInterrupt`, `SystemExit`, and `GeneratorExit`, which all inherit from `BaseException` but not from `Exception`, e.g.

```
try:
    raise SystemExit
except BaseException as e:
    print("hello world!")
```

Comment: In my case, I had to do `print(e.with_traceback(None))`, because `with_traceback` expects one argument.

Answer (score 5):

Not mentioning the type of exception you want to handle itself does the job.

Try this:

```
try:
   #code in which you expect an exception 
except:
   #prints the exception occured
```

if you want to know the type of exception that occurred:

```
try:
   # code in which you expect an exception 
except Exception as e:
   print(e)
   # for any exception to be catched
   print(type(e))
   # to know the type of exception.
```

for detailed explanation go trough this
https://www.tutorialspoint.com/python/python_exceptions.htm

Comment: ... and with `print(type(e))`  you get also the type of the error (which can be useful too)

Answer (score 3):

```
# in python 3

# if you want the error
try:
    func()
except Exception as e:
    exceptionFunc(e)

# if you simply want to know an error occurs
try:
    func()
except:
    exceptionFunc()

# if you don't even wanna do anything
try:
    func()
except:
    pass
```

Answer (score 1):

The following only worked for me (both in PY2 and PY3):

```
try:
  # (Anything that produces any kind of error)
except:
  ertype = sys.exc_info()[0]  # E.g. <class 'PermissionError'>
  description = sys.exc_info()[1]   # E.g. [Errno 13] Permission denied: ...
  # (Handle as needed )
```

Comment: but I want to pointer to `e` the exception NO MATTER THE TYPE.

Comment: @CharlieParker You offered the bounty but never awarded it, did you solve your issue?

Answer (score 0):

**Built-In Exceptions in Python**

Built-In exception classes are divided into **Base error classes** from which the error classes are defined and **Concrete error classes** which define exceptions which you are more likely to see time to time.

The more detailed document about the buit-In exception can be found in [https://docs.python.org/3/library/exceptions.html]

**Custom Exceptions**

It is used to fit your specific application situation. For example, you can create your own exception as RecipeNotValidError as the recipe is not valid in your class for developing a cooking app.

**Implementation**

```py
class RecipeNotValidError(Exception):    
    def __init__(self):       
        self.message = "Your recipe is not valid"        
        try:            
            raise RecipeNotValidError
        except RecipeNotValidError as e:            
            print(e.message)
```

These are custom exceptions that are not defined in the standard library. The steps you can follow to create custom classes are :

1. Subclass the Exception class.
2. Create a new Exception class of your choice.
3. Write your code and use the try...except flow to capture and handle your custom exception.

Comment: Yes, but the question here was "how to catch any exception and get its error object?" It was about handling even unexpected errors.