# Bad idea to catch all exceptions in Python

Tags: python, exception

Why is it a bad idea to catch all exceptions in Python ?

I understand that catching all exceptions using the `except:` clause will even catch the 'special' python exceptions: `SystemExit`, `KeyboardInterrupt`, and `GeneratorExit`. So why not just use a `except Exception:` clause to catch all exceptions?

Comment: Gotta catch 'em all

Answer (score 29, accepted):

Because it's terribly nonspecific and it doesn't enable you to do anything interesting with the exception. Moreover, if you're catching every exception there could be loads of exceptions that are happening that you don't even know are happening (which could cause your application to fail without you really knowing why). You should be able to predict (either through reading documentation or experimentation) specifically which exceptions you need to handle and how to handle them, but if you're blindly suppressing all of them from the beginning you'll never know.

So, by popular request, here's an example. A programmer is writing Python code and she gets an `IOError`. Instead of investigating further, she decides to catch all exceptions:

```
def foo():
    try:
        f = open("file.txt")
        lines = f.readlines()
        return lines[0]
    except:
        return None
```

She doesn't realize the issue in her ways: what if the file exists and is accessible, but it is empty? Then this code will raise an `IndexError` (since the list `lines` is empty). So she'll spend hours wondering why she's getting `None` back from this function when the file exists and isn't locked without realizing something that would be obvious if she had been more specific in catching errors, which is that she's accessing data that might not exist.

Comment: @Raffe: Can you give specific examples please ?

Comment: @Bandicoot specific examples of why catching all exceptions is a bad idea?

Comment: @Raffe: Yup. Will help me understand your answer better. Thanks !

Comment: @Bandicoot updated. Basically, the idea is that exceptions are a debugging tool that you throw away when you catch all of them without regard to what they actually are.

Comment: If there's a typo at, say, `lines = f.readlins()` it will also be silently caught by the exception. Bottom line - *debug hell*

Comment: May be the late one but what if I catch exception message with catchall exception and printing it? .Allow me to debug issues

Comment: @nagato if you don't catch the exception, it will automatically get printed by the interpreter when it falls through and causes the program to exit. (You're running your program from some kind of console when you're debugging, right?) Otherwise, if you need to log it to a file instead, you can very well re-raise the exception after logging (and possibly flushing).

Answer (score 5):

Because you probably want to handle each exception differently. It's not the same thing to have a KeyInterrupt than to have a Encoding problem, or an OS one... You can catch specific exceptions one after the other.

```
try:
    XXX
except TYPE:
    YYY
except TYPE:
    ZZZ
```