# Pythonic way to handle errors and exceptions

Tags: python, optimization, error-handling, coding-style, try-catch

Some time ago I wrote a piece of code, a Flask route to log out users from a web application I was working on, that looked like that:

```
@app.route('/logout')
@login_required
def logout():
    # lets get the user cookie, and if it exists, delete it
    cookie = request.cookies.get('app_login')
    response = make_response(redirect(url_for('login')))
    if cookie:
        riak_bucket = riak_connect('sessions')
        riak_bucket.get(cookie).delete()
        response.delete_cookie('app_login', None)
        return response
    return response
```

I did its job, and was certainly working, but now I am getting into making the app more robust by adding proper error handling, something that I havent done before on a large scale nowhere in my code. So I stumbled on this route function and I started writing its new version, when I realised I dont know how to do it 'the right way'. Here is what I came up with:

```
@app.route('/logout')
@login_required
def logout():
    # why dont we call variables after what they are in specifics?
    login_redirect = make_response(redirect(url_for('login')))
    try:
        cookie = request.cookies.get('app_login')
    except:
        return login_redirect
    # if we are here, the above try/except went good, right?
    try:
        # perhaps sessions_bucket should really be bucket_object?
        # is it valid to chain try statements like that, or should they be
        # tried separately one by one?
        sessions_bucket = riak_connect('sessions')
        sessions_bucket.get(cookie).delete()
        login_redirect.delete_cookie('app_login', None)
    except:
        return login_redirect
    # return redirect by default, just because it seems more secure
    return login_redirect
```

It also does it job, but still doesnt look 'right' to me. So, the question are, to all of you who have larger experience in writing really pythonic Python code, given the fact I would love the code to handle all errors nicely, be readable to others and do its job fast and well (in this particular case but also in rest of rather large codebase):

- how are you calling your variables, extra specific or general: sessions_bucket vs riak_bucket vs bucket_object?
- how do you handle errors, by usage of try/except one after another, or by nesting one try/except in another, or in any other way?
- is it ok to do more than one thing in one try/except, or not?
- and perhaps anything else, that comes to your mind to the above code examples

Thanks in advance!

Comment: To be frank, with the exception of inline comments, your use of try-except looks correct to me. Sure, you can get super pedantic about it, but from a pragmatic point of view your code is fine.

Comment: rdodev: the comments in the second example are my doubts about the code being correct, and are meant to be answered here. Did you also talked about the first example comments, and if so, what's wrong with them, and what is the better way?

Comment: I think catch all exceptions are generally a bad idea. http://stackoverflow.com/questions/10594113/bad-idea-to-catch-all-exceptions-in-python

Comment: @WilliamDenman is not a bad idea, per se. It's just that, if you don't specify the exception type, there is a small chance you can catch stuff that isn't related to the code within it. By the same token specifying which exceptions to catch, you can miss important ones and letting the code run in an undesirable state. In other words, a catch-all is a safety net if you aren't sure all the possible exceptions your code can throw.

Answer (score -1):

I don't know the exact riak python API, so I don't know what exceptions are thrown. On the other hand, how should the web app behave on the different error conditions? Has the user to be informed?

- Variable names: I prefer generic. If you change the implementation (e.g. Session store), you don't have to change the variable names.
- Exceptions: Depends on the desired behavior. If you want to recover from errors, try/except one after another. (Generally, linear code is simpler.) If you don't recover from errors, I find one bigger try clause with several exception clauses very acceptable.
- For me it's ok to do several things in one try/except. If there are too many try/except clauses, the code gets less readable.
- More things: logging. logging.exception will log the traceback so you can know where exactly the error appeared.

Some suggestion:

```
import logging
log = loggin.getLogger(__name__)

@app.route('/logout')
@login_required
def logout():
    login_redirect = make_response(redirect(url_for('login')))
    try:
        sessionid = request.cookies.get('app_login', None)
    except AttributeError:
        sessionid = None
        log.error("Improperly configured")
    if sessionid:
        try:
            session_store = riak_connect('sessions')
            session = session_store.get(sessionid)
            if session:
                session.delete()
            login_redirect.delete_cookie('app_login', None)
        except IOError:  # what errors appear when connect fails?
            log.exception("during logout")
    return login_redirect
```

Comment: I dont see it as a very good suggestion, because it does not solves anything, nor answers my questions. In addition to that, in second except catch you're stating there were issues deleting session info, while the try could fail on first line, that is database connection - not exactly issues deleting cookie.

Comment: I tried to improve the following things: 1. Log the exception with a backtrace so you can exactly know where the code failed. I tried to maintain the same behavior, not informing the error to the user.  2. Variable naming: if you move the session store to something else without "buckets" your code still is ok. The use of buckets is an implementation detail. 3. Reduce exit points. I'll try to improve the answer.