# using a lots of try...except in Django for logging every error

Tags: python, django, exception

i want to check every line or process of my code and if is not success, then log the error. like this:

```
try:
   handle = open('file.txt', 'r+')
   txt = handle.read()
except:
   logger.info("SOME DESCRIPTION OF ERROR")
```

it works but it seems this solution is not the best way. or is this a good way of using a lots of try... except statement? is there an alternative solution?

Comment: You really should *not* use `try... except:` without specifying which exception you want to catch. See [this](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/21553327/why-is-except-pass-a-bad-programming-practice) questions to understand why.

Comment: https://github.com/getsentry/sentry, Isn't every error logged by your server with a full traceback?

Comment: yes, it logs, but i have to log a description of the error.

Comment: Which information you must include in that description that isn't covered by the default log?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

First off. As @Bakuriu said you must avoid using a bare `except`.

Second off. Django (from 1.4 onward) comes with logging configured for you.

Take a loog at https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/dev/topics/logging/. In production (ie: `DEBUG = False`) it will catch every exception and send it to you via email. Provided you have correctly setup the `ADMIN` key in your `settings.py`.

For instance, this logger:

```
LOGGING = {
    'version': 1,
    'formatters':{ 'verbose': {
            'format': '%(levelname)s %(asctime)s %(module)s %(process)d %(thread)d %(message)s'
        },
    },
    'handlers': {
        'error_file': {
            'level': 'ERROR',
            'class': 'logging.FileHandler',
            'filename': 'errors.log',
            'formatter': 'verbose'
        },
    },
    'loggers': {
        'django.request': {
            'handlers': ['error_file'],
            'level': 'INFO',
            'propagate': False,
        },
    }
}
```

Will log anything with level `ERROR` and upper to the error.log file at the root of your project. That includes exception tracebacks and full stack information.