# Check user input is valid for decimal?

Tags: python, python-2.7, while-loop, user-input

I want to make sure the input will be number. I have tried testing with signs and letters but the shell just throws an error saying "Invalid literal for Decimal". I'm working on a calculator so thought the decimal module would be best suited. Thanks in advance.

This is my code:

```
import decimal

while True:
 userInput = (raw_input("Enter number:"))
 try:
  userInput = decimal.Decimal(userInput)
  break
 except ValueError:
  print ("Number please")
```

Using Python 2.7.6

Comment: Your code seems to do what you ask for - it will detect an error in in input and ask again.

Comment: It seems a different exception than `ValueError` is thrown. Try just `except:`, i.e. catch-all, or better: `except decimal.InvalidOperation:`

Comment: @tobias_k: No! Please don't advocate Pokemon exception handling. You can catch multiple explicit exception types instead. Also see [Why is "except: pass" a bad programming practice?](http://stackoverflow.com/q/21553327)

Answer (score 9, accepted):

Catch **decimal.InvalidOperation**

```
>>> a = 's'
>>> try:
...     decimal.Decimal(a)
... except decimal.InvalidOperation:
...     print 'fds'
... 
fds
```

Answer (score 3):

Instead of catching a `ValueError`, catch a `decimal.InvalidOperation` error. This error is thrown when invalid data is passed to the `decimal.Decimal` constructor.

Answer (score 1):

The correct way to check if a value is a valid input for Decimal is:

```
from decimal import Decimal, DecimalException

try:
    Decimal(input_value)
except DecimalException:
    pass
```

https://docs.python.org/2/library/decimal.html#decimal.DecimalException

Answer (score 0):

You are catching the wrong Exception. You are catching a [ValueError](https://docs.python.org/2/library/exceptions.html#exceptions.ValueError), but the code throws [`decimal.InvalidOperation`](https://docs.python.org/2/library/decimal.html#decimal.InvalidOperation) for various inputs that are not valid decimal values.

```
>python test.py
Enter number:10

>python test.py
Enter number:10.2

>python test.py
Enter number:asdf
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "test.py", line 6, in <module>
    userInput = decimal.Decimal(userInput)
  File "C:\Python27\lib\decimal.py", line 548, in __new__
    "Invalid literal for Decimal: %r" % value)
  File "C:\Python27\lib\decimal.py", line 3872, in _raise_error
    raise error(explanation)
decimal.InvalidOperation: Invalid literal for Decimal: 'asdf'

>python test.py
Enter number:10.23.23
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "test.py", line 6, in <module>
    userInput = decimal.Decimal(userInput)
  File "C:\Python27\lib\decimal.py", line 548, in __new__
    "Invalid literal for Decimal: %r" % value)
  File "C:\Python27\lib\decimal.py", line 3872, in _raise_error
    raise error(explanation)
decimal.InvalidOperation: Invalid literal for Decimal: '10.23.23'
```

Change your `except` line to `except decimal.InvalidOperation:`