# should I always know the type of my exception before I catch it?

Tags: java, python, c++, exception

For example, is it considered bad practice to write:

```
try
{
  #some code
}
catch (Exception e){
  #some code
}
```

Rather than

```
try
{
  #some code
}
catch (ExceptionName e){  #like ArrayIndexOutOfBoundsException
  #some code
}
```

I guess the question holds for pretty much every language, be it Python, C++, Java...Any thoughts?

I am asking because it seems to me that you shouldn't, since it means you don't know what kind of error you are handling and what to do with it, but I see some people do it.

Comment: It's certainly bad practice in Python...

Comment: Depends on the context.

Comment: It's bad practice. You always want the most specific exception type.

Comment: Both have uses, but the latter should be used a lot more frequently than the latter.

Comment: This question assumes that it doesn't matter what your exception handler does.  What are you doing?  That will tell you what you should be catching.

Comment: the latter should be used more frequently than the latter??

Comment: This question, while interesting, is a bad fit for SO because it is too broad and subjective.  http://programmers.stackexchange.com/ would be a better place to ask this.

Comment: agreed. It does not imply one single answer, but is more a question about good practices, what people think is right. If you tell me how to migrate it, I'll do.

Comment: @Barnabe - I have flagged the question and asked a moderator to migrate it.  They will take it from here. :)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

YES!

There is a single exception to this:

*You want to catch, do something, then re-throw*.  Maybe you have some resources you need to close before the exception goes up, or you want to inform the user something wrong has happened:

```
FileResource fileResource = new FileResource("/some/path");
try {
    fileResource.open();
    fileResource.dostuff();
    //other logic
} catch (Exception e){
    fileResource.close();
    throw e;
}
```

Hence, when an exception gets thrown, you can close your resources before the program exits.

Always catch the most specific exception type you can.

Also, catching all Exceptions is exceptionally bad in Python, because you can catch syntax exceptions and the like.

Comment: If you can detail just a little bit more your example about catch-do-rethrow, it will be great.

Comment: Thanks for the edit. Crystal clear.

Comment: Shouldn't you use a `finally` block instead? And doesn't this lose information about where specifically the exception came from?

Comment: @user3580294: This is more of a language-agnostic question.  For Java, yes, `finally` is probably a better better choice.  Also, in Java, you don't lose any info this way (The stack trace is generated when you create a new Exception, not when you rethrow it)

Comment: Ah, right, missed the other language tags. My mistake. Didn't realize that the stack trace was generated when the exception was created either. Thanks!

Answer (score 2):

Not always, you'll want a graceful exit if your code fails if it's in production. So there's a good case for broader error handling.

```
def main():
    try:
        primary_process()
    except Exception as e: # Base error class that excludes keyboard interrupts
        logging.Error(e)   # and other things you don't want to catch.
```

But most of the time in your code you only handle as specific errors as you expect:

```
def something()
    part1() # don't expect the potential error to affect this, 
    part2() # so leave out of try block
    try:        # this infrequently raises an error for some reason, for now, 
        part3() # can't avoid. But we can handle if it happens.
    except LookupError as e: # specific error expected very infrequently
        handle(e)
    part4()
```

Another relevant Q&A: [Why is "except: pass" a bad programming practice?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/21553327/why-is-except-pass-a-bad-programming-practice/21563149#21563149)

Comment: Yeah, I just saw that one, it is a great answer as well, thanks a lot for the link, and also for your answer, it is completely clear, I really feel I learnt something today.

Answer (score 1):

Yes. It is always a good practice to know exactly what type of exception you are catching because it helps in better handling

Comment: If you should always know exactly what type of exception you are catching, then shouldn't you just handle this is a more graceful way other than catching the exception?  (See Aaron Hall's answer).

Comment: You cannot always know about all the exceptions for example runtime time exceptions. But you should handle all other exceptions which you think your try can throw so that you can have a better idea of what went wrong. Also you can still catch exceptions of type Exception after it missed all your specific exceptions, so that you can end gracefully.Ex: try{ //some code} catch(SomeException1 s1){ // } catch(SomeException2 s2){ // } catch(Exception s3) { ///end gracefully }