# Converting python2 code to python3 problems

Tags: python, networking, python-3.x, chat, python-2.x

So I have been trying too convert an omegle bot, which was written in python2, to python3. This is the original code: https://gist.github.com/thefinn93/1543082

Now this is my code:

```
import requests
import sys
import json
import urllib
import random
import time

server = b"odo-bucket.omegle.com"

debug_log = False   # Set to FALSE to disable excessive messages
config = {'verbose': open("/dev/null","w")}
headers = {}
headers['Referer'] = b'http://odo-bucket.omegle.com/'
headers['Connection'] = b'keep-alive'
headers['User-Agent'] = b'Mozilla/5.0 (X11; Linux x86_64) AppleWebKit/535.2 (KHTML, like Gecko) Ubuntu/11.10 Chromium/15.0.874.106 Chrome/15.0.874.106 Safari/535.2'
headers['Content-type'] = b'application/x-www-form-urlencoded; charset=UTF-8'
headers['Accept'] = b'application/json'
headers['Accept-Encoding'] = b'gzip,deflate,sdch'
headers['Accept-Language'] = b'en-US'
headers['Accept-Charset'] = b'ISO-8859-1,utf-8;q=0.7,*;q=0.3'

if debug_log:
    config['verbose'] = debug_log

def debug(msg):
    if debug_log:
        print("DEBUG: " + str(msg))
        debug_log.write(str(msg) + "\n")

def getcookies():
    r = requests.get(b"http://" + server + b"/")
    debug(r.cookies)
    return(r.cookies)

def start():
    r = requests.request(b"POST", b"http://" + server + b"/start?rcs=1&spid=", data=b"rcs=1&spid=", headers=headers)
    omegle_id = r.content.strip(b"\"")
    print("Got ID: " + str(omegle_id))
    cookies = getcookies()
    event(omegle_id, cookies)

def send(omegle_id, cookies, msg):
    r = requests.request(b"POST","http://" + server + "/send", data="msg=" + urllib.quote_plus(msg) + "&id=" + omegle_id, headers=headers, cookies=cookies)
    if r.content == "win":
        print("You: " + msg)
    else:
        print("Error sending message, check the log")
        debug(r.content)

def event(omegle_id, cookies):
    captcha = False
    next = False
    r = requests.request(b"POST",b"http://" + server + b"/events",data=b"id=" + omegle_id, cookies=cookies, headers=headers)
    try:
        parsed = json.loads(r.content)
        for e in parsed:
            if e[0] == "waiting":
                print("Waiting for a connection...")
            elif e[0] == "count":
                print("There are " + str(e[1]) + " people connected to Omegle")
            elif e[0] == "connected":
                print("Connection established!")
                send(omegle_id, cookies, "HI I just want to talk ;_;")
            elif e[0] == "typing":
                print("Stranger is typing...")
            elif e[0] == "stoppedTyping":
                print ("Stranger stopped typing")
            elif e[0] == "gotMessage":
                print("Stranger: " + e[1])
                try:
                    cat=""
                    time.sleep(random.randint(1,5))
                    i_r=random.randint(1,8)
                    if i_r==1:
                        cat="that's cute :3"
                    elif i_r==2:
                        cat="yeah, guess your right.."
                    elif i_r==3:
                        cat="yeah, tell me something about yourself!!"
                    elif i_r==4:
                        cat="what's up"
                    elif i_r==5:
                        cat="me too"
                    else:
                        time.sleep(random.randint(3,9))
                        send(omegle_id, cookies, "I really have to tell you something...")
                    time.sleep(random.randint(3,9))
                    cat="I love you."

                    send(omegle_id, cookies, cat)
                except:
                    debug("Send errors!")
            elif e[0] == "strangerDisconnected":
                print("Stranger Disconnected")
                next = True
            elif e[0] == "suggestSpyee":
                print ("Omegle thinks you should be a spy. Fuck omegle.")
            elif e[0] == "recaptchaRequired":
                print("Omegle think's you're a bot (now where would it get a silly idea like that?). Fuckin omegle. Recaptcha code: " + e[1])
                captcha = True

    except:
        print("Derka derka derka")
    if next:
        print("Reconnecting...")
        start()
    elif not captcha:
        event(omegle_id, cookies)

start()
```

The error I get is:

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "p3.py", line 124, in <module>
    start()
  File "p3.py", line 46, in start
    r = requests.request(b"POST", b"http://" + server + b"/start?rcs=1&spid=", data=b"rcs=1&spid=", headers=headers)
  File "/usr/lib/python3.4/site-packages/requests/api.py", line 44, in request
    return session.request(method=method, url=url, **kwargs)
  File "/usr/lib/python3.4/site-packages/requests/sessions.py", line 456, in request
    resp = self.send(prep, **send_kwargs)
  File "/usr/lib/python3.4/site-packages/requests/sessions.py", line 553, in send
    adapter = self.get_adapter(url=request.url)
  File "/usr/lib/python3.4/site-packages/requests/sessions.py", line 608, in get_adapter
    raise InvalidSchema("No connection adapters were found for '%s'" % url)
requests.exceptions.InvalidSchema: No connection adapters were found for 'b'http://odo-bucket.omegle.com/start?rcs=1&spid=''
```

I didn't really understand what would fix this error, nor what the problem really is, even after looking it up.

UPDATE:
Now after removing all the b's I get the following error:

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "p3.py", line 124, in <module>
    start()
  File "p3.py", line 47, in start
    omegle_id = r.content.strip("\"")
TypeError: Type str doesn't support the buffer API
```

UPDATE 2:
After putting the b back to r.content, I get the following error message:

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "p3.py", line 124, in <module>
    start()
  File "p3.py", line 50, in start
    event(omegle_id, cookies)
  File "p3.py", line 63, in event
    r = requests.request("POST","http://" + server + "/events",data="id=" + omegle_id,   cookies=cookies, headers=headers)
TypeError: Can't convert 'bytes' object to str implicitly
```

UPDATE 3:
Everytime I try to start it excepts "Derka derka", what could be causing this (It wasn't like that with python2).

Comment: Have you tried running `2to3`? It will usually identify problems like this, and can often even fix them automatically.

Answer (score 4):

`requests` takes *strings*, not `bytes` values for the URL.

Because your URLs are `bytes` values, `requests` is converting them to strings with `str()`, and the resulting string contains the characters `b'` at the start. That's no a valid scheme like `http://` or `https://`.

The *majority* of your bytestrings should really be regular strings instead; only the `content.strip()` call deals with actual bytes.

The headers will be encoded for you, for example. Don't even set the Content-Type header; `requests` will take care of that for you if you pass in a dictionary (using string keys and values) to the `data` keyword argument.

You shouldn't set the `Connection` header either; leave connection management to `requests` as well.

Comment: Now I get the following error message:                          Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "p3.py", line 124, in <module>
    start()
  File "p3.py", line 47, in start
    omegle_id = r.content.strip("\"")
TypeError: Type str doesn't support the buffer API

Comment: So I can just delete the whole header section?

Comment: I did say `r.content` is a bytes value; that is why you get your error. If the server is returning JSON however, why not use the `response.json()` method instead?

Comment: The rest of the headers may play a role, no need to ditch it all.

Comment: so I put the b back to r.content, and now I get the following error message:    Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "p3.py", line 124, in <module>
    start()
  File "p3.py", line 50, in start
    event(omegle_id, cookies)
  File "p3.py", line 63, in event
    r = requests.request("POST","http://" + server + "/events",data="id=" + omegle_id, cookies=cookies, headers=headers)
TypeError: Can't convert 'bytes' object to str implicitly

Comment: You are still mixing bytes and strings somewhere. The `data` parameter will have to be bytes too unless you use a dictionary instead (recommended here).

Comment: Okay thanks I set added the b's to the data parameters, but now my code excepts "Derka derka", this wasn't like that with python2. Any suggestions what I might have done wrong?

Comment: Remove the blanket except (see [Why is "except: pass" a bad programming practice?](http://stackoverflow.com/q/21553327)) so you can see what the error is.