# Handling varying json response

Tags: python, json, properties, decorator

So I'm working with an an API that returns a JSON after I send a query to it. I wrote a wrapper class around that JSON response so I could handle any change in the JSON in one place. It also helps that I can access the values easily now.

Here is the wrapper I wrote:

```
class WitResponse:
    def __init__(self, json_string):
        self.json_string = json_string
        self.wit_response = json.loads(json_string)

    @property
    def intent(self):
        return self.wit_response["outcomes"][0]["intent"]

    @property
    def confidence(self):
        return self.wit_response["outcomes"][0]["confidence"]

    @property
    def text(self):
        return self.wit_response["_text"] 

    @property
    def entites(self):
        return self.wit_response["outcomes"][0]["entites"]

    @property
    def msg_id(self):
        return self.wit_response["msg_id"] 

    @property
    def response(self):
        return self.json_string.translate(None,"\n")+"\n" #Saves the reply in an already easy to send format

    @property
    def target(self):
        return self.wit_response["outcomes"][0]["entities"]["target"][0]["value"]
```

An example of a very frequent key that can be found in the JSON is the `target` key (as it can be seen above). Since it doesn't always exist calling the `target` method will raise an exception. I'm looking for a solution to handle fields like that that'll be as elegant as possible.

At the moment I've just wrapped the the return statement in the `target` method with a try,except block and returns `None` if an exception is raised (the JSON didn't have a `target` key).

I've also considered using a decorator that adds the try,except block however it didn't seem to work when I added the decorator above the @property decorator:

```
def None_Return_Value_Decorator(func):
    def wrapper(self):
        try:
            value = func(self)
            return value
        except:
            return None

    return wrapper
```

Are there more elegant solutions? If not, can the decorator one work (and how do I fix it if it does)?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Add your decorator *below* the `@property` decorator:

```
@property
@None_Return_Value_Decorator
def target(self):
    return self.wit_response["outcomes"][0]["entities"]["target"][0]["value"]
```

Now your decorator is applied first, before turning the return value of your decorator into the property getter.

You want to [avoid using a except handler](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/21553327/why-is-except-pass-a-bad-programming-practice) however; try to only catch a relevant exception, such as `IndexError` and `KeyError`.

You can make the exceptions configurable in the decorator:

```
from functools import wraps

def ignore_exception(*exceptions):
    def decorator(f):
        @wraps(f)
        def wrapper(*args, **kw):
            try:
                return f(*args, **kw)
            except exceptions:
                return None
        return wrapper
    return decorator
```

then use as:

```
@property
@ignore_exception(KeyError)
def target(self):
    return self.wit_response["outcomes"][0]["entities"]["target"][0]["value"]
```

for example.

Comment: That seems to work.
Are you aware of a better way to handle this than I already have? This seems very inelegant to me.

Comment: @Shookie: if you are using Python 3.4 you can use the new [`contextlib.suppress()` context manager](https://docs.python.org/3/library/contextlib.html#contextlib.suppress).

Comment: @Shookie: but using a decorator to encapsulate common handling looks fine to me; you could make the decorator accept the exception(s) to catch as an argument even.