# Is this function correct?

Tags: python

Is it correct to call that function in some exceptions ?
Is that process correct ? Is it better to process each exceptions ?

```
def close_all():
        try:
                ftp.close()
        except:
                pass
        try:
                tar.close()
        except:
                pass
        try:
                savelist.close()
        except:
                pass
        try:
                os.remove(tarname)
        except:
                pass
        exit()
```

Thanks in advance.

Comment: Why not a single `try` if you are going to `pass` all exceptions?

Comment: @BlueMoon Because if one throws, the following code won't be executed. I'd recommend not capturing all exceptions though.

Comment: Naked `except` is [frowned upon](http://blog.codekills.net/2011/09/29/the-evils-of--except--/) (at the *very least*, use `except Exception`). If you're using Python 3.4, you can use [`contextlib.suppress`](https://docs.python.org/3.4/library/contextlib.html#contextlib.suppress) to make it neater.

Comment: See [Why is "except: pass" a bad programming practice?](http://stackoverflow.com/q/21553327)

Answer (score 1):

I think you should handle each exception one by one. This will shorten your code. First of all note all the exceptions that `ftp.close()` and other methods will raise. Then handle them one by one.

**Example:**

```
>>> a = 5        # a is an integer
>>> b = "Bingo"  # b is a string
>>>
>>> def add_five():
        try:
            c + 5  # c is not defined. NameError exception is raised
        except NameError:
            b + 5  # b is a string. TypeError exception is raised
        except TypeError:
            a + 5  # a is int. No exception is raised
        except:
            # This last except clause is just in case you forgot to handle any exception
            pass 
>>>
```

Comment: How does catching more exceptions make the code shorter?

Comment: @TimCastelijns Well, you won't have to write `try` statement again and again.

Comment: Yeah ok. I was hinting at Colonel's comment above