# How to properly use try/except in Python

Tags: python, pymongo

I have a function that returns the DB connection handler from MongoDB. I have various other functions that makes a call to the DB, I figure let's throw the connection handler into a function so I don't have to define it in every function.

Does this look right? I guess my question is, if it can't make a connection to the DB server, it will print both messages `Could not connect to server` and `No hosts found` How can I go about only printing "Could not connect to the server."

```
def mongodb_conn():
    try:
        conn = pymongo.MongoClient()
    except pymongo.errors.ConnectionFailure, e:
        print "Could not connect to server: %s" % e
    return conn

def get_hosts()
    try:
        conn = mongodb_conn()
        mongodb = conn.dbname.collection

        b = []
        hosts_obj = mongodb.find({'_id': 'PR'})
        for x in hosts_obj:
            print x
    except:
        print "No hosts found"

get_hosts()
```

Comment: In `mongodb_conn` there could be error: if exception occurs, conn would _never_ be defined!

Comment: maybe `except: pass`

Comment: @pss arrghh, please do not recommend that, it is absolutely horrible.

Answer (score 14, accepted):

Move your `conn = mongodb_conn()` call *out* of the `try .. except` handler, and test if `None` was returned:

```
def get_hosts()
    conn = mongodb_conn()
    if conn is None:
        # no connection, exit early
        return

    try:
        mongodb = conn.dbname.collection

        b = []
        hosts_obj = mongodb.find({'_id': 'PR'})
        for x in hosts_obj:
            print x
    except:
        print "No hosts found"
```

You should, at all cost, avoid using a blanket `except` however; you are catching *everything* now, including memory errors and keyboard interrupts, see [Why is "except: pass" a bad programming practice?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/21553327/why-is-except-pass-a-bad-programming-practice)

Use specific exceptions *only*; you can use one `except` statement to catch multiple exception types:

```
except (AttributeError, pymongo.errors.OperationFailure):
```

or you can use multiple `except` statements handle different exceptions in different ways.

Limit the exception handler to just those parts of the code where the exception can be thrown. The `for x in hosts_obj:` loop for example is probably not going to throw an `AttributeError` exception, so it should probably not be part of the `try` block.

Note that you'll need to adjust your `mongodb_conn()` function to not try and use the `conn` local if it has never been set; you'll get an `UnboundLocal` error if you do:

```
def mongodb_conn():
    try:
        return pymongo.MongoClient()
    except pymongo.errors.ConnectionFailure, e:
        print "Could not connect to server: %s" % e
```

Now the function returns the connection if successful, `None` if the connection failed.

Comment: @PadraicCunningham: *what* will throw a connection error?

Comment: nothing I did not realize you changed the code around but you do now catch all exceptions instead of what was in the OP's original code no?

Comment: @PadraicCunningham: the original code catches all exceptions. That was what the question was about.

Comment: Doesn't work as expected...  The ConnectionFailure exception does not occur for an invalid connection string, for example. Prefer @Pallav answer.

Comment: @EduardoLucio: if you say so, I just took that from the question. My answer talks about how to handle connection failures, not how to best detect those.

Answer (score 1):

You can also check if the server is available
like this:

```
        from pymongo.errors import ConnectionFailure
        client = MongoClient()
        try:
            # The ismaster command is cheap and does not require auth.
            client.admin.command('ismaster')
        except ConnectionFailure:
            print("Server not available")
```