# What is the optimal use of a lock with a try ... except in Python 2.7?

Tags: python, locking, python-multithreading

Suppose that I have a `threading.Lock()` object that I want to acquire in order to use a resource. Suppose I want to use a `try ... except ...` clause with the resource.

There are several ways of doing this.

**Method 1**

```
import threading
lock = threading.Lock()
try:
    with lock:
        do_stuff1()
        do_stuff2()
except:
    do_other_stuff()
```

If an error occurs during `do_stuff1()` or `do_stuff2()`, will the lock be released? Or is it better to use one of the following methods?

**Method 2**

```
with lock:
    try:
        do_stuff1()
        do_stuff2()
    except:
        do_other_stuff()
```

**Method 3**

```
lock.acquire():
try:
    do_stuff1()
    do_stuff2()
except:
    do_other_stuff()
finally:
    lock.release()
```

Which method is best for the lock to be released even if an error occurs?

Comment: [`try:..except:pass`](http://stackoverflow.com/q/21553327/1903116) is very bad.

Comment: I personally prefer 1st method without `try..except`

Comment: This is the *whole point* of `with`, the `__exit__` part of the context manager releases the lock whatever happens. If you want to catch errors in what you do with it, the `try` should be *inside* the `with` (Method 2).

Comment: @thefourtheye it's an example, I know that ... thanks though :-)

Comment: The first method releases the lock _before_ calling `do_other_stuff()` thus you reduce the time the lock is taken, reducing contention. Perhaps by a minimal factor, but still.

Comment: @jonrsharpe thanks ... feel free to post your comment as an answer. That's probably as good as it gets.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

The `with` ["context manager"](https://www.python.org/dev/peps/pep-0343/) requires an `__exit__` method, which in this case will ensure that, whatever happens, the `lock` is `release`d.

If you want to handle exceptions that occur during whatever it is that you're doing with that `lock`, you should put the `try` *inside* the `with` block, i.e. Method 2 is the correct approach. In general, you should always aim to minimise the amount of code within the `try` block.

You should also be as specific as possible about what *could* go wrong; a bare `except:` is bad practice (see e.g. [*"the evils of `except`"*](http://blog.codekills.net/2011/09/29/the-evils-of--except--/)). At the *very least* (even for a simple example!) you should use `except Exception:`.