# To compare two pointer locations in Python

Tags: python, python-2.7, pointers

Code

```
import sys
import os

fp = open("/home/masi/r3.raw", "rb")

try:
    events = []
    while aBuf[:4] != b'\xFA\xFA\xFA\xFA':
        aBuf = fp.read(4)
        events.append(aBuf)         
        if aBuf == os.SEEK_END:
            # pointer cannot be outside of file so minus 144
            fileEnding = aBuf[os.SEEK_END - 144 : os.SEEK_END]
except:
    print "File end at position : ", fp.tell()
    import traceback
    traceback.print_exc()

finally:
    fp.close()
```

where I know that the following is never true

```
        if aBuf == os.SEEK_END:
            # pointer cannot be outside of file so minus 144
            fileEnding = aBuf[os.SEEK_END - 144 : os.SEEK_END]
```

I am comparing the pointer with the end pointer of the file, at least I am expecting so but it does not seem to correct.

### Improved Code from skrrgwasme and martineau's contributions

```
import sys
import os
import struct
import binascii

file_name = "/home/masi/r.raw"
file_size = os.path.getsize(file_name)
print "File size is : ", file_size
read_size = 4
read_count = 0

aBuf = b'\x00\x00\x00\x00' # don't forget to create your variables before you try to read from them
fileEnding = ""
fp = open(file_name, "rb")

try:
    aBuf = fp.read(read_size)
    read_count += read_size
    event_starts = []
    event_ends = []
    event_starts.append(read_count)
    while aBuf and read_count < file_size:
        if aBuf[:read_size] == b'\xFA\xFA\xFA\xFA':
            event_ends.append(read_count)
            if read_count + 1 < file_size: event_starts.append(read_count + 1)

        aBuf = fp.read(read_size)
        read_count += read_size
        print "RC ", read_count, ", remaining: ", 1.0-float(read_count)/file_size, "%"

    if read_count >= file_size: break

except:
    print "File end at position : ", fp.tell()
    import traceback
    traceback.print_exc()

finally:
    # store to partial index of postgres database: event pointers
    fp.close()
```

How can you compare location of two pointers?

Comment: The Python documentation for [`os.SEEK_END`](https://docs.python.org/2/library/os.html?highlight=os.seek_end#os.SEEK_END) says it's a predefined constant value that can be passed as a parameter to the [`os.lseek()`](https://docs.python.org/2/library/os.html?highlight=os.seek_end#os.lseek) function.If you want to know the current position of an open file use [`file.tell()`](https://docs.python.org/2/library/stdtypes.html?highlight=tell#file.tell). The length of a file can be obtained with [`os.path.getsize()`](https://docs.python.org/2/library/os.path.html?highlight=getsize#os.path.getsize).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you take a look at the Python source code for the [os module](https://hg.python.org/cpython/file/2d9003d44694/Lib/os.py#l211), you'll see that `os.SEEK_END` isn't automatically set to the size of your file. It's just a constant that is set equal to the integer 2. [It is intended to be used as a parameter for the lseek() function](https://docs.python.org/2/library/os.html#os.SEEK_END).

You need to get the file size in bytes first, then compare your file pointer to that. You can use [os.path.getsize(path)](https://docs.python.org/2/library/os.path.html#os.path.getsize) to get your file size in bytes. Your comparison was never true because you were reading four bytes at a time, so your file pointer skipped from byte 0 to byte 4, passing over 2, which is the value of `os.SEEK_END`.

Suggested code:

```
import sys
import os

file_name = "/home/masi/r3.raw"
file_size = os.path.getsize(file_name)
read_size = 4
read_count = 0
# you could use fp.tell() in the loop instead of manually incrementing
# your own count of the file position instead, but this will avoid a lot of
# extra fp.tell() calls in the loop

aBuf = b'\x00\x00\x00\x00' # don't forget to create your variables before you try to
                           # read from them
fp = open(file_name, "rb")

try:
    events = []
    while aBuf[:read_size] != b'\xFA\xFA\xFA\xFA':
        aBuf = fp.read(read_size)
        events.append(aBuf)
        read_count += read_size         
        if read_count >= file_size:
            # pointer cannot be outside of file so minus 144
            fileEnding = aBuf[file_size - 144 : file_size]
            break
except:
    print "File end at position : ", fp.tell()
    import traceback
    traceback.print_exc()

finally:
    fp.close()
```

Notes:

1. Instead of comparing for *exactly* the file size you expect, I suggest using a greater than or equal comparison (`>=`). Since you're reading four bytes at a time, if you have an odd file size, your comparison will never be true.
2. After you get this code working, I'd suggest taking it over to [Code Review Stack Exchange](https://codereview.stackexchange.com/). As martineau has helpfully pointed out in the comments, there are a number of issues and potential pitfalls in your code that are worth correcting.

Comment: `if aBuf >= file_size:`? How can you compare a 4 byte string to an integer?

Comment: @martineau Good catch. I forgot to add the manual bytes read count.

Comment: Makes better sense now. Suggest you also see the part about catching _any_ exception in the accepted anwser to [_Why is “except: pass” a bad programming practice?_](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/21553327/why-is-except-pass-a-bad-programming-practice).

Comment: @martineau I strongly agree that it's bad practice. I just copied the OP's code and made my changes to it. I suppose it would be good to suggest that, though.

Comment: There's still a number of issues. Here's a few. The empty `except` is potentially going to hide the fact that `aBuf = fp.read(readsize)` references an undefined variable. Even if you fix that, the `while` loop will never end if the file doesn't contain a `b'\xFA\xFA\xFA\xFA'` on a four-byte boundary before the end of the file is encountered. If the `fileEnding = aBuf[file_size - 144 : file_size]` ever executes, it will likely set `fileEnding` to `''` because `Abuf` will never have more than 4 bytes in it. Lastly, your code also assumes the `fp.read()` was always able read 4 bytes.

Comment: @martineau I agree with all of your points, but I don't really feel the need to correct all of them for this answer. I've edited it to suggest he go over to Code Review to get help cleaning it up.

Comment: Yes, the code was horrible. I changed the main loop to be like reading a book until the `read_count` reaches `file_size`. Do I skip any more critical exceptions?