# Error on read gzip csv from url in Python: "_csv.Error: line contains NULL byte"

Tags: python, csv, gzip, urllib2, urlopen

I am trying to read a gzipped csv file from a url. This is a very big file with more than 50.000 lines. When I try the code below I get an error: `_csv.Error: line contains NULL byte`

```
import csv
import urllib2   
url = '[my-url-to-csv-file].gz'
response = urllib2.urlopen(url)
cr = csv.reader(response)

for row in cr:
    if len(row) <= 1: continue
        print row
```

If I try to print the content of the file before I try to read it I get something like this:

> ?M}?7?M==??7M???z?YJ?????5{Ci?jK??3b??p?
>
> ?[?=?j&=????=?0u'???}mwBt??-E?m??Ծ??????WM??wj??Z??ėe?D?VF????4=Y?Y?tA???

How can I read the gzipped csv file from this URL properly?

Comment: I don't think you need `csv.reader` here...have you tried `response = urllib2.urlopen(url)` `data = response.read()` `response.close()` `for line in data: print line`?

Comment: If I try this method I get content but it is bad encoded I think, I get something like: ```%
s
Z
?
o
?
J
1
v
?
}
?
?
D
?
?
?
?
?
?
?
?
?

?```

Comment: try `for line in data: line = line.decode('utf-8') print line` https://docs.python.org/dev/tutorial/stdlib.html#internet-access

Comment: yes tried that but I get errors, does it matter that the csv in gzip?

Comment: It does matter; see my answer below.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

**How to Open a .gz (gzip) csv File from a URL with `urllib2.urlopen`**

1. Save the URL data to a file object.  For this, you can use [`StringIO.StringIO()`](https://docs.python.org/2/library/stringio.html#module-StringIO).
2. Decompress the .gz with [`gzip.Gzipfile()`](https://docs.python.org/2/library/gzip.html#gzip.GzipFile).
3. Read the data from your new file object.

To use your example:

```
from StringIO import StringIO
import gzip
import urllib2

url = '[my-url-to-csv-file].gz'
mem = StringIO(urlopen(url).read())
f = gzip.GzipFile(fileobj=mem, mode='rb')
data = f.read()

for line in data:
  print line
```

Answer (score 0):

Use a try and except, and if you don't care what happens when you encounter a `NULL` row, just use `pass`:

```
for row in cr:
    try:
        if len(row) <= 1: continue
            print row
    except Exception, e:
        print e
        #or if you're not worried about errors, you can use pass
```

Comment: Egad!  This is definitely not ideal - http://stackoverflow.com/questions/21553327/why-is-except-pass-a-bad-programming-practice

Comment: Sure, that's true. they could also do: `except Exception, e: print e` and then they can read their data without the programming being interrupted by `NULL` bytes.

Comment: odd I still get the same error, but the erroris on the ```for row in cr:``` line