# Why use contextlib.suppress as opposed to try/except with pass?

Tags: python, python-3.x

Why would one use [`contextlib.suppress`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/contextlib.html#contextlib.suppress) to suppress an exception, instead of `try`/`except` with a `pass`?

There is no difference in the amount of characters between these two methods (if anything, `suppress` has more characters), and even though code is often counted in LOC instead of characters, `suppress` also seems to be much slower than `try`/`except` in both cases, when an error is raised and when it's not:

```
Python 3.5.0 (v3.5.0:374f501f4567, Sep 13 2015, 02:27:37) [MSC v.1900 64 bit (AMD64)] on win32
Type "copyright", "credits" or "license()" for more information.
>>> from timeit import timeit
>>> # With an error
>>> timeit("""with suppress(ValueError):
    x = int('a')""", setup="from contextlib import suppress")
1.9571568971892543
>>> timeit("""try:
    x = int('a')
except ValueError:
    pass""")
1.0758466499161656
>>> # With no error
>>> timeit("""with suppress(ValueError):
    x = int(3)""", setup="from contextlib import suppress")
0.7513525708063895
>>> timeit("""try:
    x = int(3)
except ValueError:
    pass""")
0.10141028937128027
>>>
```

Comment: It saves two lines. It improves readability a lot if you have several consecutive blocks like this

Comment: Similarly, why use `any()` or `all()` when you can use a for loop? I think using `contextlib.suppress` helps with readability and maintenance.

Comment: @SimeonVisser `any()` and `all()` *clearly* make the code shorter, both line wise and character wise. I'm also pretty sure `any()` and `all()` are performance wise faster than a `for` loop. As far as I can see, the only reason to use `suppress` is that it's a bit more readable (and evne this is debatable as it takes more characters). Using `try/except` is *much* faster on the other hand.

Comment: That's true. Perhaps it has to do with taking a functional programming (i.e., passing `contextlib.suppress` around to conditionally suppress exceptions in some situations but not others)?

Comment: [relevant Python issue](http://bugs.python.org/issue15806)

Answer (score 69, accepted):

It is two lines less code without sacrificing readability.

It might be especially convenient for nested or consecutive code blocks. Compare:

```
try:
    a()
    try:
        b()
    except B:
        pass
except A:
    pass
```

vs.:

```
with suppress(A):
    a()
    with suppress(B):
        b()
```

It also allows to express the intent:

- `with suppress(SpecificError): do_something()` says *don't propagate the error if it is raised while doing something*
- `try: do_something() except SpecificError: pass` says *do something and don't propagate the error if it is raised*

It is less important because most people won't notice the difference.

Answer (score 20):

Conceptually, for me, the contextlib.suppress approach allows me to handle errors that are likely to occur (such as attempting to remove a file that may not actually be there). try/except then becomes a more active handling of 'this should not happen' events (such as a divide by 0 or inability to open a few to which I want to write).