# subclass of error which counts how many times it gets raised

Tags: python, python-3.x, error-handling

A certain error message in a script is currently being caught in a try except block. For the intended use, this is going to let an error happen too often and I am wondering if there is a neat and tidy way to create a subclass from an error which counts how many times it happens before triggering.

The following illustrates the desired behaviour. Without any handling:

```
from random import randint
for i in range(100):
    print(1 / randint(0, 10))
```

outputs:

```
0.1111111111111111
0.1
0.25
0.3333333333333333
0.1
0.2
0.16666666666666666
1.0
0.1
0.5
1.0

---------------------------------------------------------------------------
ZeroDivisionError                         Traceback (most recent call last)
<ipython-input-11-bfba3ff98af3> in <module>()
      1 from random import randint
      2 for i in range(100):
----> 3     print(1 / randint(0, 10))

ZeroDivisionError: division by zero
```

Can you do this somehow:

```
class MoreThanFiveZeroDiv(ZeroDivisionError):
    pass
```

such that when you run this:

```
from random import randint
for i in range(100):
    try:
         print(1 / randint(0, 10))
    except MoreThanFiveZeroDiv
```

it only triggers when it happens for the fifth time?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You basically don't need a custom exception class for this task. Instead, you can use a counter variable and just increase it up until it satisfies your intended constraints:

```
In [41]: counter = 0

In [42]: from random import randint
    ...: for i in range(100):
    ...:     try:
    ...:         print(1 / randint(0, 10))
    ...:     except ZeroDivisionError as exc:
    ...:         if counter > 5:
    ...:             raise Exception("More thatn 5 times ZeroDivisionError!")
    ...:         counter += 1
```

If you are looking for a more neater way you can use a custom class to store the counter in it and handles the condition checking inside itself:

```
In [57]: class MoreThanFiveZeroDiv:  
    ...:     def __init__(self):
    ...:         self.counter = 0
    ...:                             
    ...:     def __call__(self, exc):
    ...:         if type(exc) is ZeroDivisionError:
    ...:             if self.counter > 5:
    ...:                 raise exc
    ...:             self.counter += 1
    ...:         else:
    ...:             raise exc
```

Then you can use it like following:

```
 mtfz = MoreThanFiveZeroDiv()

for i in range(100):
    try:
        print(1 / randint(0, 10))
    except Exception as exc:
        mtfz(exc)
```

Comment: Thanks, the thing is, in the existing code, which involves an api query, there are several loops with try-except blocks in them. I also read about [contextlib](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/34566806/why-use-contextlib-suppress-as-opposed-to-try-except-with-pass/) as a possible solution before asking the question. Yes, counters can be built into the code, but it would be neater if one class could be defined somewhere and then just put into the existing `except` statements without harming the readability of the code.

Comment: @cardamom The problem with your syntax is that if the exception name after `except` is not exactlly the same
as the the exception that is just happened Python won't call your exception class even if you've
inherited from `Exception` class or that particualr exception. Therefore, a simple way
is to use a variable to counting the exceptions by yourself. Or doing that process with another object that is called after catching the exception.

Comment: Thanks, I am thinking about the solution still. Have realised that these exception classes being classes rather than class-instances probably can't even hold a count so am not sure if the answer I was hoping for exists, will give it a bit longer otherwise accept your answer.

Comment: It's usually better to use `isinstance` instead of checking for a specific type. i.e. `if isinstance(exc, ZeroDivisionError):`.

Comment: @martineau Yes it's usually better but here I really didn't see any need to accept instances of subtypes of that particular exception class. We need an explicit identity check.

Comment: That's because your answer isn't as generic as it could be.

Comment: @martineau Yes, I just updated code thanks for now though.

Answer (score 1):

I think @Kasramvd has a good idea, but could be improved by making it more generic and not hardcode so many values into it. Here's an implementation that doesn't:

```
from random import randint, seed
seed(42)  # Use same "random" sequence every run for testing.


class ConditionallySuppress:
    def __init__(self, exception_class, max_count):
        self.max_count = max_count
        self.counter = 0
        self.exception_class = exception_class

    def __call__(self, exc):
        if not isinstance(exc, self.exception_class):  # Unsuppressed?
            raise
        else:
            self.counter += 1
            if self.counter > self.max_count:  # Threshold exceeded?
                class_name = self.exception_class.__name__
                print(' - More than {} {}s have occurred'.format(self.max_count,
                                                                 class_name))
                raise


conditionally_suppress = ConditionallySuppress(ZeroDivisionError, 5)
for i in range(100):
    try:
        d = randint(0, 10)
        print('i: {}, d: {}{}'.format(i, d, '' if d else ' ZERODIV!'), end='', flush=True)
#        # Uncomment to test some other exception occurring.
#        if i == 5:
#            print(' raising RuntimeError')
#            raise RuntimeError
        print(', 1/d: {}'.format(1/d))
    except Exception as exc:
        conditionally_suppress(exc)
        print()

print('processing finished')
```

Comment: Thanks, I actually added those non-hard coded features exception_class and max_count when I implemented it earlier. Another thing I realised it needed is an `else` for `if isinstance(exc, self.exception_class):` Became aware of this in testing. If you don't have that, any other kind of exception will fail to raise.