# "with"-like syntax for calling next on an iterator?

Tags: python, python-3.x

EDIT: this is a duplicate of [How to properly ignore exceptions](https://stackoverflow.com/q/730764/972499).

My code:

```
try:
    y = next(x)
    z = next(y)
    f(y, z)
except StopIteration:
    pass
```

What I'd like to write instead:

```
with x as y, y as z:
    f(y, z)
```

However, that raises `AttributeError: __enter__`.

If `with` is not the appropriate idiom, is there a different idiomatic way to do what I'm doing without the explicit `except StopIteration: pass`, or is there a way to wrap an iterator in a type that supports `with`? The semantics should be exactly the same as in the first snippet.

I'm asking because `for y in x` will not work in this context.

Comment: The purpose of `with` is to automatically clean up a resource when the block is exited. What does that have to do with iterators?

Comment: It's incredibly difficult to imagine the context that makes any of this code make sense, nor that would explain why you can't use `for` with an iterator. It would probably help to see how `x` 's type is defined, and what problem you are trying to solve via `f`.

Comment: As the question specifically asks, if `with` is not the appropriate idiom for ignoring `StopIteration` , is there a **different** idiom that's appropriate?

Comment: What is your criteria for rejecting the explicit ``try`` syntax? Are you looking for *shorter* code? Is your goal to not protect ``f`` against ``StopIteration`` (which the ``try:`` does but not the ``with``)? Is there some reason why ``x`` has to be unwrapped like this, and could it possibly be circumvented?

Comment: It's not that complicated. It just asks for a way to catch and ignore `StopIteration` without the explicit `except StopIteration`. The motive is exactly as people answered on [Why use contextlib.suppress?](https://stackoverflow.com/q/34566806/972499). A perfectly valid and informative answer would be "there's no feature for specifically ignoring `StopIteration`, but here's a feature for ignoring any exceptions you specify", and that's exactly what the accepted answer does.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use [`contextlib.suppress(*exceptions)`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/contextlib.html#contextlib.suppress) to shorten `try:`-`except (*exceptions,): pass` constructs:

```
from contextlib import suppress

with suppress(StopIteration):
    y = next(x)
    f(y, next(y))
```

A syntax such as `with helper(x) as y, helper(y) as z:` is not possible: A context manager *must*  return a value or raise an Exception. This makes it impossible to gracefully handle the case when `next(x)` or `next(y)` do not return a value.

Answer (score 2):

If you want to retrieve one item from an iterator, the way to do that is `next`. There's no separate idiom for it; `next` is the dedicated "get one thing from an iterator" function. `with` definitely isn't it; `with` is for resource cleanup.

Your code is bizarre enough that it's hard to imagine a dedicated syntax ever being added for it.

If you really want to write it differently, you could do something like

```
for y in x:
    for z in y:
        f(y, z)
        break
    break
```

or

```
from itertools import islice

for y in islice(x, 1):
    for z in islice(y, 1):
        f(y, z)
```