# Python ignore all exceptions and procede

Tags: python, exception, try-catch

Hello this question is about python.

Is there a way to ignore all kinds off exceptions. I know i could just put the whole code in an huge try cahtch but i want it to continue even if one part fails and in result of this some other parts fail too. One way to achieve this would be to put every single line in a try except statement. But is there an other more elegant way to do this?

Comment: I think [`contextlib.suppress`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/contextlib.html#contextlib.suppress) seems like what you're looking for; you can wrap your `main()` function in a `with supress(exception_types)`, seemingly: https://stackoverflow.com/q/34566806/6273251

Comment: That's a really, really bad idea.

Comment: Exceptions are raised for all kinds of reasons, many of which aren't recoverable. What do you mean by "ignore"? As a side note, I don't think "ignoring" all exceptions can ever be called "elegant".

Comment: by "ignore" im mean it does not matter and the programm shoud just procede

Answer (score 0):

Well , you can
1 - Put every separate part in a try catch

```
try:
  #something
except:
  pass
```

2 - Put everything in a bigger try catch

```
try:
  #do something
  #so something else
  #do something else
except:
  pass
```

or you can use contextlib.suppress (https://docs.python.org/3/library/contextlib.html#contextlib.suppress) as Random Davis suggested to ignore certain types of exceptions

But ignoring all exception is a really bad idea , instead you should do

```
try:
  #something
except:
  #something else
```

As far as I know , there is no other "elegant" way to ignore exceptions

(This could have been a comment but I lack rep to post comments)

Comment: Yea but the difference between these two is that in nr 2 if the second statement fails, the third will not be executet.

Answer (score 0):

Besides using try, my python professor will generally comment out a function that he isn't testing so he could test a specific function. If part of your code isn't working try adding a breakpoint before debugging, then you can run your code up until the breakpoint to see if a certain line is doing what you want it to. In visual studio code you can do this by clicking in the empty space just to the left of the line numbers, and you will see a red dot on the line if done correctly.

If you are referencing that a function isn't doing what you want it to do, employing these methods will help you find the error in your ways, starting with tracking the input all the way until you get the output you want, going function by function.

If you're referencing that your code is simply too broken to function correctly, your code will always run until it returns an error, and if the error is early in that process between converting an input to an output, you can come across a multitude of reasons behind this that will stop functions that are supposed to run afterwards from working correctly. If that is the case comment out the later functions until your first one is working, and keep working chronologically to debug those errors. In the future, I highly recommend posting your exact code when asking a coding question, otherwise it can be hard for others to extract the necessary information to answer your question effectively. Good luck!

In reference to Global-Occult's answer, although you can basically try something and except extraneous information, you really don't want to be coding like that, because to develop higher level programs that extra information will no longer be extraneous, in fact it could be very important data that will allow you to develop a program much further.