# ImportError for python 3.5 (driver cannot be found)

Tags: python, python-3.x, importerror

I want to understand how does Python search for files using its search path. I have the following error:

```css
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "C:\Users\Rusk\Desktop\BBone_RTL-SDR\codes\lab6.py", line 9, in <module>
    import rtlsdr
  File "C:\Program Files (x86)\Python3.5\lib\site-packages\rtlsdr\__init__.py", line 50, in <module>
    from .librtlsdr import librtlsdr
  File "C:\Program Files (x86)\Python3.5\lib\site-packages\rtlsdr\librtlsdr.py", line 41, in <module>
    librtlsdr = load_librtlsdr()
  File "C:\Program Files (x86)\Python3.5\lib\site-packages\rtlsdr\librtlsdr.py", line 36, in load_librtlsdr
    raise ImportError('Error loading librtlsdr. Make sure librtlsdr '\
ImportError: Error loading librtlsdr. Make sure librtlsdr (and all of its dependencies) are in your path
```

I have verified that all of the modules and dependencies have been installed using pip. Ihe function of load_lbrtlsdr() is as such:

```html
def load_librtlsdr():
    driver_files = ['rtlsdr.dll', 'librtlsdr.so']
    driver_files += ['..//rtlsdr.dll', '..//librtlsdr.so']
    driver_files += ['rtlsdr//rtlsdr.dll', 'rtlsdr//librtlsdr.so']
    driver_files += [find_library('rtlsdr'), find_library('librtlsdr')]

    dll = None

    for driver in driver_files:
        try:
            dll = CDLL(driver)
            break
        except:
            pass
    else:
        raise ImportError('Error loading librtlsdr. Make sure librtlsdr '\
                          '(and all of its dependencies) are in your path')

    return dll
```

It seems that the reason i encountered this error was because the program failed to locate the driver (.dll) which is located in my main desktop screen. I had edited the environment variable to include the path to the location of the driver but the error persists. I have been stuck trying to find alternatives but nothing seems to work. Could someone kindly elp me out or direct me towards some direction? Thanks! I am just 5 days old with Python. I am using a 64-bit windows OS by the way.

Comment: `try... except` tends to hide the true error message. What happens if you just try `from .librtlsdr import librtlsdr`?

Comment: @paragbaxi Do you mean to execute just the line from .librtlsdr import librtlsdr?

Comment: Let me clarify. I'd like to see the raw error message. It may reveal more. Try the code without the try/except. [Here's why.](http://stackoverflow.com/a/21553825/564514)