# Printing the max number in a list without max()

Tags: python, python-3.x

I'm having trouble protecting my script from crashing when the user inputs an invalid value to store into a 'number' variable.

**Purpose of program:** Allow user to enter integers, stores them into a list, then finds and prints the highest number. Does not allow for strings or floats in input.

**Functions:**

1. `getNum(prompt)` -  to test and convert the inputted value to integer and returns y.
2. `swap(A, x, y)` - simple swap routine function to sort the data. (Not currently in use)
3. `sortNum(A)`  - to sort and use the Swap routine in the list.
4. `maxIt(numbers)` - to find the highest number in the list. (IN USE), I don't think I even need to sort the list if I'm using this max function.
5. `main()`

**Code:**

```
def getNum(prompt):
    # Function to call when asking for the numbers later.
    # Try/except to catch crashes if failing to store integer.
    try:
        x = input(prompt)
        y = int(x)
        return y

    # Message to print when excepting.
    except:
        print("I was expecting an integer number, please try again... \n")


# Function to swap to highest # in list 'numbers'.
def swap(A, x, y):
    temp1 = A[x]
    A[x] = A[y]
    A[y] = temp1

# Function to perform the looping/swap routine.
# Program can find max with separate function.
## This function is to sort the numbers in the list.
def sortNum(A):
    for i in range(len(A)):
        for k in range(len(A) - 1):
            first = k
            second = k + 1

            if (A[first] > A[second]):
                # Uses Swap function
                swap(A, first, second)

# Function to find the highest number in the list.
def maxIt(numbers):
    maxNum = numbers[0]
    for i in numbers:
        if i > maxNum:
            maxNum = i
    return maxNum

# Start main
def main():

    # Creates the numbers array.
    numbers = []

    # Starts the loop to enter numbers into the array.
    done = False
    while not done:
        numInput = getNum("Please enter an integer or < 0 to finish >: ")

        # Stores every input from numInput into numbers.
        numbers.append(numInput)

        #  Test condition to break out of loop '0'.
        if numInput is 0:

            # Prints the resulting max number once finished.
            print("The maximum value is: " + str(maxIt(numbers)))

            # Flag to stop the program once finished.
            done = True

main()
```

Current Output when not failing getNum's test (str or float):

```
Please enter an integer or < 0 to finish >: 222
Please enter an integer or < 0 to finish >: 333
Please enter an integer or < 0 to finish >: 444
Please enter an integer or < 0 to finish >: 555
Please enter an integer or < 0 to finish >: 666
Please enter an integer or < 0 to finish >: 777
Please enter an integer or < 0 to finish >: 888
Please enter an integer or < 0 to finish >: 999
Please enter an integer or < 0 to finish >: 0
The maximum value is: 999
```

Errors when entering a str or float into getNum/numInput:

```
Please enter an integer or < 0 to finish >: 222
Please enter an integer or < 0 to finish >: 333
Please enter an integer or < 0 to finish >: 444
Please enter an integer or < 0 to finish >: test
I was expecting an integer number, please try again...

Please enter an integer or < 0 to finish >: 555
Please enter an integer or < 0 to finish >: 666
Please enter an integer or < 0 to finish >: 0
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "C:\Users\Bar\Desktop\IS115\Peretz_A9.py", line 64, in <module>
    main()
  File "C:\Users\Bar\Desktop\IS115\Peretz_A9.py", line 59, in main
    print("The maximum value is: " + str(maxIt(numbers)))
  File "C:\Users\Bar\Desktop\IS115\Peretz_A9.py", line 37, in maxIt
    if i > maxNum:
TypeError: '>' not supported between instances of 'NoneType' and 'int'
```

Comment: The problem is that your try except returns null rather than looping

Comment: Also you should be more specific with error handling - `except ValueError` - and keep the try block as short as you can.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Well, the problem is that your function `getNum` return a None when the number is not valid, try the following for a quick fix:

```
if numInput is not None:
    numbers.append(numInput)
```

But i also suggest that you read:

[Why is "except: pass" a bad programming practice?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/21553327/why-is-except-pass-a-bad-programming-practice)

And try to avoid the empty except clause in your code!

Answer (score 1):

The problem is your `try..except` not returning anything (returning `None`) in the exceptional case:

```
def getNum(prompt):
    # Function to call when asking for the numbers later.
    # Try/except to catch crashes if failing to store integer.
    try:
        x = input(prompt)
        y = int(x)
        return y

    # Message to print when excepting.
    except:
        print("I was expecting an integer number, please try again... \n")
        # Returns None resulting in your error
```

You can avoid this by placing your input in a loop:

```
def getNum(prompt):
    # Function to call when asking for the numbers later.
    # Try/except to catch crashes if failing to store integer.
    while True:
        try:
            x = input(prompt)
            y = int(x)
            return y

        # Message to print when excepting.
        except ValueError:
            print("I was expecting an integer number, please try again... \n")
```

Answer (score 0):

The problem is located in the function `getNum`. Actually, when you are typing some text in the input, the function `getNum` reach an exception  because you are trying to cast not digit `str` into `int` then the message is printed and the function returns... `None`. `None` is stored into numInput then added to the list. You know what follows.

In order to make this work, you should test the output of `getNum`.

Answer (score 0):

Your `getNum` returns either an int or None (after printing the message).  `main` unconditionally appends the return value even if None.  Hence the comparison message.  Change

```
    numbers.append(numInput)
```

to

```
    if isinstance(numInput, int):
        numbers.append(numInput)
```