# Call different function based on condition in try catch block in Python

Tags: python, try-catch

I have a code where I am supposed to call different functions based on conditions. Below is my code

```
try:
    if condition_1 is True:
        function1()
    if condition_2 is True:
        function2()
    if condition_3 is True:
        function3()

except Exception, e:
    raise e
```

There are cases when multiple conditions can be true. So multiple function needs to be called and executed.
It worked fine until today when 1 of the function raised an exception.

`condition_1` and `condition_3` were true. So `function1` and `function3` were supposed to be executed.
When it called `function1` , because of some error in `function1`, it raised an exception, without executing `function3` . What I wanted, is that even if `function1` raises error, it should still continue and check other conditions and execute respective functions accordingly.

1 way to resolve this is to write each if condition in separate try/catch block. But, is there a better way to resolve this?

Comment: wrap the function you want its errors to be ignored and continue in its own try/except block, on the except part you can just type  `pass` or log the error message or something.

Comment: do as @dopstar says and just call each function in its own `try` `except`

Comment: Why not map your functions in a dict and and put the try/catch in a loop? Pseudo code: For every condition[n]; TRY to call function[n]; catch err; loop to next

Answer (score 1):

In my opinion, exceptions must be allowed to the interrupt the process if anything goes wrong in the way. However, you can achieve this behavior by removing `raise` keyword.

```
try:
    if condition_1 :
        function1()
    if condition_2 :
        function2()
    if condition_3 :
        function3()
except Exception, e:
    pass
```

Please take a look at [Why is “except: pass” a bad programming practice?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/21553327/why-is-except-pass-a-bad-programming-practice)

P.S.: You do not need to check if `True is True` in conditions.