# Using Google Api Speech Recognition with Python, Interfacing with tkinter

Tags: python, api, speech-recognition

I was trying to code a search engine with speak recognition, using Tkinter interface.  When i try to run, it works fine. But when i try to click on microphone, it stops working. I couldn't get where is the error. My google api key is not private, but please do not use it. Codes are in the link below:
https://github.com/AntonioDaSilva/SpeechRecognition
Thank you all.

Comment: You should not ignore the exceptions with simple `pass`, exceptions provide valuable information about errors. http://stackoverflow.com/questions/21553327/why-is-except-pass-a-bad-programming-practice

Comment: yeah it's true but i think it is not the real problem in my program. When i click on microphone, i hear the first sound but it does not send it to search after i talk.

Comment: I think exception happens but you simply ignore it

Comment: ok i will have a look at code, thanks :D