# How do I remove the "u" prefix from a (json serialized) list of dictionaries?

Tags: javascript, python, json, django, unicode

I need the "u" prefixed removed because I am passing these json serialized lists over to the front end and handling them with javascript. Javascript can not make sense of these "u"'s.

Here is the code:

```
context['list_of_dicts'] = serialize('json', my_list_of_dicts)
# this function is wrapped with a @json response decorator
```

@json_response looks like:

```
def json_response(func):
    """
    A decorator thats takes a view response and turns it
    into json. If a callback is added through GET or POST
    the response is JSONP.
    """ 
    def decorator(request, *args, **kwargs):
        objects = func(request, *args, **kwargs)
        if isinstance(objects, HttpResponse):
            return objects
        try:
            data = simplejson.dumps(objects)
            if 'callback' in request.REQUEST:
                # a jsonp response!
                data = '%s(%s);' % (request.REQUEST['callback'], data)
                return HttpResponse(data, "text/javascript")
        except:
            data = simplejson.dumps(str(objects))
        return HttpResponse(data, "application/json")
    return decorator
```

On the frontend, I get the error:

```
Uncaught SyntaxError: Unexpected token u in JSON at position 0
```

That's because the "u" prefix has not been removed. How do I remove the "u" prefix so my frontend can decode the JSON?

Comment: What is `serialize`, and if you want JSON why aren't you using `json`?

Comment: @jonrsharpe: Django method, I think.

Comment: I've edited the question to include more code

Comment: Please give a [mcve] with correct formatting. If you have a decorator that's turning the response into JSON, why are you also serialising it yourself?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You are serialising your data **three times**. First with:

```
context['list_of_dicts'] = serialize('json', my_list_of_dicts)
```

and then two times more with:

```
data = simplejson.dumps(str(objects))
```

This encodes a `str()` representation of the `objects` returned from your view function, which is then converted to a JSON string document. The `str()` conversion adds the `u` prefix; you are serialising a Unicode string object literal:

```
>>> context = {}
>>> context['list_of_dicts'] = u'<Some JSON literal here, correctly encoded>'
>>> import json
>>> json.dumps(str(context))
'"{\'list_of_dicts\': u\'<Some JSON literal here, correctly encoded>\'}"'
```

Your decorator has several more issues:

- you are using a blanket `except` handler, so you are masking whatever error the first attempt at serialising with `simplejson.dumps()` threw. Never use a blanket `except` and silence the exception. You now don't know what went wrong there. Also see [Why is "except: pass" a bad programming practice?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/21553327/why-is-except-pass-a-bad-programming-practice)
- you appear to be serialising objects into a dictionary; if you want to send back a JSON object, construct something consisting only of Python objects **first**, then serialise the whole.
- if you need custom serialisation logic (like using the [Django serialisation framework](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/stable/topics/serialization/#serializing-data)), don't use a `@json_response` decorator to re-encode, or at the very least return a `HttpResponse` instance to avoid being serialised *again*.

Comment: Three times; they don't just `dumps(objects)`, they call `str` on it too!