# confused about exception handling with shutil.copyfile and os.makedirs

Tags: python

I've been reading that you shouldn't just use 'pass' when using try/except in python.  I have a couple of situations where I use it in:

```
source = os.listdir("../myprogdir") # directory where original configs are located
destination = '//' + servername + r'/c$/remotedir/' # destination server directory
for files in source:
    if files.endswith("myconfig.exe.config"):
        try:
            os.makedirs(destination, exist_ok=True)
            shutil.copy(files,destination)
        except:
            pass
```

and

```
  source = r'//' + servername + '/c$/remotedir/'
  dest = r"../myprogdir"
  file = "myconfig.exe.config"
  if os.path.isfile(os.path.join(source, file)):  # isfile checks if filename already exists on remote computer
      try:
          shutil.copyfile(os.path.join(source, file), os.path.join(dest, file))

      except:
          print (" Local directory you are copying to does not exist.")
  else:
      print (" ...filename does not exist...")
```

The thing is, I am using these in functions where I run through multiple computers in a list that I have.  If I throw an error such as a computer being down/turned off or a directory/filename does not exist, I just want to skip over it into the next computer name on my list.

So is it ok to use pass in this situation?  I guess something could happen if the user running my program does not have permission to perform some of the functions.

What situations would I need to use proper exception handling?

How can I write out a permissions exception error?  That is the only thing that might cause a problem with the program.  Even though the only people running the program should have proper permissions anyways.

Comment: Never use a bare `except:`. If there's a specific type of exception you're expecting, catch that specific type of exception. This isn't Pokemon; don't try to catch 'em all.

Comment: It would be a lot better of you caught the *explicit exceptions*. As it stands, *any* error will pass silently. *Errors should never pass silently.
Unless explicitly silenced...*

Comment: I think [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/21553327/why-is-except-pass-a-bad-programming-practice) may be a duplicate. If people agree, I will close.

Comment: So if I don't care if a file/directory doesn't exist and don't care if the computer I am connecting to doesnt exist or is turned off, what other kinds of errors would I be looking for?  General Windows errors?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Don't think of the `pass` statement as having anything to do with exception handling *per se*.

The `pass` statement only says, "this space intentionally left blank". `pass` simply tells the Python interpreter that nothing happens here, and that's not a syntax error.

There are other cases where `pass` is useful, outside of exception handling. For instance, maybe you want to define a class that doesn't actually do anything, but that inherits from another class without changing anything:

```
class Person(object):
    pass

class Man(Person):
    """A manly person"""

class Woman(Person):
    pass
```

Here, we have 3 classes, none of which have methods beyond those inherited from `object`.

Note that instead of a `pass` statement in `Man`, I put a docstring. This is functionally-equivalent to `pass` in the context of a class/function/method definition. (You wouldn't, however, be able to replace the `pass` in an `except` block by a docstring)

To return to your question, think of the `except` block as being the code that runs when something hasn't worked out the way you hoped. Here, you are saying `pass`, which is to say, "Just ignore any errors".

You could also put a simple `raise` statement instead of the `pass`, to propagate the exception to the enclosing block, all the way up the call stack. This would be functionally-equivalent to leaving out the `try`/`except` block altogether.

You could do much more here, as well. Depending on how you want your application to behave when it encounters a failed attempt to do something useful, you could log a message, break out of the loop, re-queue the action for a later retry, increment an error counter, and so on.