# Transforming Tweepy data from text file into dataframe

Tags: python, python-3.x, pandas, dataframe

I am trying to create a dataframe from tweepy data I pulled into a text file.

however, when I try to create the dataframe with the columns I want, nothing is generated. The code runs, but there is just no output.

Below is the code:

#writing text file
with open("jsontweet3.txt", "a") as txtfile:
    txtfile.write('tweet_id retweet_count favorite_count \n')

```
#pulling tweet info
for tweet_id in fdf.tweet_id:
    try:
        twitinfo = tweetapi.get_status(str(tweet_id), tweet_mode='extended')

    except:
        # Not able to get tweet --> add to failed_tweets list
        failed_tweets.append(tweet_id)

    else:
        # only gets executed if the try clause did not fail         
        retweets = twitinfo.retweet_count
        favorites = twitinfo.favorite_count
        txtfile.write(str(twitinfo)+' '+str(retweets)+' '+str(favorites)+'\n')


tdf = pd.DataFrame(columns=['tweet_id','retweet_count','favorite_count'])
with open('jsontweet3.txt','r') as file:

for line in file:
    twitinfo,retweets,favorites= line[:-1].split(' ')
    tdf = tdf.append({'tweet_id':twitinfo,'retweet_count':retweets,'favorite_count':favorites},ignore_index=True)
```

tdf

All help is greatly appreciated!

Comment: The `for` loop needs to be indented as it should be it inside the `with`. And I think the `for` line should be `for line in file.readlines():`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Aside from my comments on the indentation of the `for` loop and the `.readlines()`, I'd suggest either:

1) writing the tweepy data as a csv (separate with commas, instead of spaces) and then `pd.read_csv()` will generate the csv

2) creating the dataframe at the same time you are creating the text file. Simply generate the tdf before the first `for`, and then have your `tdf.append()` line as you doing the `txtfile.write()`