# Url parameter in Template - ID - Django

Tags: django

```
 path('clock/view/<user_id>', views.ClockInOutViewListView.as_view(), name='admin_timesheet_clock_in_out_view'),
```

I am passing `user_id` in url and looks like this -

```
http://localhost:8000/timesheet/clock/view/13
```

I want that `user_id` in my template to reuse that `user_id` Example - `13`.

I was trying to `{{user_id}}` in my template but it did not got any value

How can i get that `13` value in my template which is passed in my url

```
class ClockInOutViewListView(LoginRequiredMixin, generic.TemplateView):
    template_name = 'clock/clock-view.html'

    def get_context_data(self, user_id, **kwargs):   
        context = super(ClockInOutViewListView, self).get_context_data(**kwargs)
        try:
            context['views'] = TimesheetEntry.objects.filter(
                                    timesheet_users = user_id,
                                ).order_by('-id')
        except: pass

        return context
```

Comment: can you add the `ClockInOutViewListView` class?

Comment: Here i added please see

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can access the **`user_id`** by **`self.kwargs['user_id']`** where the **`self`** is the view instance

try this,

```
class ClockInOutViewListView(LoginRequiredMixin, generic.TemplateView):
    template_name = 'clock/clock-view.html'

    def get_context_data(self, **kwargs):
        user_id = self.kwargs['user_id']
        context = super(ClockInOutViewListView, self).get_context_data(**kwargs)
        context['user_id'] = user_id
        return context
```

Now, you can access the `user_id`  in your template as **`{{ user_id }}`**

---

Apart from that, I would suggest to avoide bare `try..except pass` block, because it's bad behavoiur
Read more here .. [**Why is “except: pass” a bad programming practice?**](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/21553327/why-is-except-pass-a-bad-programming-practice)

Comment: `{{request.GET.param1}}` is there like this. But i don't have param1 in my url