# If I want to catch and log (not raise) exceptions, should KeyboardInterrupt be the only raised exception?

Tags: python, python-3.x, exception, logging

In the case of exceptions, I want the program to catch them, log them, then move on to the next iteration. Obviously a KeyboardInterrupt should still be raised so that the program can be stopped, but are there any other exceptions I should raise?

Very rough example of code below. This is a decorator which catches exceptions and logs them. Basically, should I have any other `except` cases?

```py
def exception_logger(func):

    @wraps(func)
    def wrapper(*args, **kwargs):

        # Run as normal
        try:
            return func(*args, **kwargs)
        except KeyboardInterrupt:
            raise

        # Any other exception that occurs is logged
        except:
            log_file = 'example.txt'
            logger = logger_format(log_file)

            logger.exception(f'\nAn exception occurred with: {func.__qualname__}\n')
            print(f'\n\nAn exception occurred with: {func.__qualname__}\nView the log file for details.\n'.upper())

    return wrapper
```

Thanks.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Instead of a blacklist (that might age poorly), you should just be catching `Exception` instead of using `except:`.  It excludes `KeyboardInterrupt` and various others you shouldn’t suppress.  (It might be OK to log them, but you don’t seem to want to do that anyway.)  See also [advice against `except: pass` in particular](https://stackoverflow.com/q/21553327/8586227) for context.