# ValueError when trying to replace invalid values with np.nan

Tags: python, pandas, numpy, csv

I am trying to create a data frame out of a space-separated dataset.  Some values in the 3rd column are missing and they're labelled `Missing_x`.  I'm trying to replace these values with `np.nan` but its throwing me a ValueError.

```
from datetime import datetime
import pandas as pd
import numpy as np

data = ["1/3/2012 16:00:00   Missing_1",
        "1/4/2012 16:00:00   27.47",
        "1/5/2012 16:00:00   27.728",
        "1/6/2012 16:00:00   28.19",
        "1/9/2012 16:00:00   28.1",
        "1/10/2012 16:00:00  28.15",
        "12/13/2012 16:00:00 27.52",
        "12/14/2012 16:00:00 Missing_19",
        "12/17/2012 16:00:00 27.215",
        "12/18/2012 16:00:00 27.63",
        "12/19/2012 16:00:00 27.73",
        "12/20/2012 16:00:00 Missing_20",
        "12/21/2012 16:00:00 27.49",
        "12/24/2012 13:00:00 27.25",
        "12/26/2012 16:00:00 27.2",
        "12/27/2012 16:00:00 27.09",
        "12/28/2012 16:00:00 26.9",
        "12/31/2012 16:00:00 26.77"]

date_list = []
mrc_list = []

for i in data:
    data = i.split('\t')
    days_of_data = datetime.strptime(data[0], '%m/%d/%Y %H:%M:%S')
    date_list.append(days_of_data)

    try:
        mrc_list.append(float(data[1]))
    except:
        mrc_list.append(np.nan)
        pass

mrc_df = pd.Series(mrc_list, index=date_list)
mrc_df.index.name = 'Date'

print(mrc_df)
```

This is the error:

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/home/onur/Documents/code-signal/mercury.py", line 37, in <module>
    days = datetime.strptime(data_list[0], '%m/%d/%Y %H:%M:%S')
  File "/home/onur/anaconda3/lib/python3.7/_strptime.py", line 577, in _strptime_datetime
    tt, fraction, gmtoff_fraction = _strptime(data_string, format)
  File "/home/onur/anaconda3/lib/python3.7/_strptime.py", line 362, in _strptime
    data_string[found.end():])
ValueError: unconverted data remains:    Missing_1
```

I understand the error.  I just don't understand why my way of addressing it does not work.

Comment: Using a bare `except` statement like that is bad practice, be careful!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You get the error because if you print out `data[0]`, it's not splitting the way you expect. It's not splitting at all in fact. Here's how you can fix your code:

```
data = ["1/3/2012 16:00:00   Missing_1",
        "1/4/2012 16:00:00   27.47",
        "1/5/2012 16:00:00   27.728",
        "1/6/2012 16:00:00   28.19",
        "1/9/2012 16:00:00   28.1",
        "1/10/2012 16:00:00  28.15",
        "12/13/2012 16:00:00 27.52",
        "12/14/2012 16:00:00 Missing_19",
        "12/17/2012 16:00:00 27.215",
        "12/18/2012 16:00:00 27.63",
        "12/19/2012 16:00:00 27.73",
        "12/20/2012 16:00:00 Missing_20",
        "12/21/2012 16:00:00 27.49",
        "12/24/2012 13:00:00 27.25",
        "12/26/2012 16:00:00 27.2",
        "12/27/2012 16:00:00 27.09",
        "12/28/2012 16:00:00 26.9",
        "12/31/2012 16:00:00 26.77"]
# Standardize the formatting...
data = [i.split() for i in data]
data = ["{} {}    {}".format(i[0].strip(), i[1].strip(), i[2].strip()) for i in data]


date_list = []
mrc_list = []

for i in data:
    # split on four spaces instead of tab (special character)
    data = i.split('    ')
    days_of_data = datetime.strptime(data[0], '%m/%d/%Y %H:%M:%S')
    date_list.append(days_of_data)

    try:
        mrc_list.append(float(data[1]))
    except:
        mrc_list.append(np.nan)
        pass

mrc_df = pd.Series(mrc_list, index=date_list)
mrc_df.index.name = 'Date'

print(mrc_df)
```

A more compact way to achieve this is:

```
from datetime import datetime
import pandas as pd
import numpy as np
from io import StringIO

data = ["1/3/2012 16:00:00   Missing_1",
        "1/4/2012 16:00:00   27.47",
        "1/5/2012 16:00:00   27.728",
        "1/6/2012 16:00:00   28.19",
        "1/9/2012 16:00:00   28.1",
        "1/10/2012 16:00:00  28.15",
        "12/13/2012 16:00:00 27.52",
        "12/14/2012 16:00:00 Missing_19",
        "12/17/2012 16:00:00 27.215",
        "12/18/2012 16:00:00 27.63",
        "12/19/2012 16:00:00 27.73",
        "12/20/2012 16:00:00 Missing_20",
        "12/21/2012 16:00:00 27.49",
        "12/24/2012 13:00:00 27.25",
        "12/26/2012 16:00:00 27.2",
        "12/27/2012 16:00:00 27.09",
        "12/28/2012 16:00:00 26.9",
        "12/31/2012 16:00:00 26.77"]
data = [i.split() for i in data]
data = ["{} {}    {}".format(i[0].strip(), i[1].strip(), i[2].strip()) for i in data]
data = ["Date    Val"] + data
mrc_df = pd.read_csv(StringIO("\n".join(data)), sep="\s\s+", engine='python')
mrc_df['Val'] = pd.to_numeric(mrc_df['Val'], errors='coerce')
mrc_df['Date'] = pd.to_datetime(mrc_df['Date'])
mrc_df.set_index('Date', inplace=True)
mrc_df.index.name = 'Date'
```

Comment: [Also, it's bad practice to be catching all exceptions](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/21553327/why-is-except-pass-a-bad-programming-practice)

Comment: You can just add that to your post, it will be more visible there.