# how can i ignore error in python properly?

Tags: python, exception, error-handling, beautifulsoup

I'm trying to web scraping.

using BeautifulSoup, i'm parsing several objects and confronted with a problem.

The problem is, i can't predict where the error occur using "find" method.

it looks like

```
a = soup.find(something).find(something)
b = soup.find(something)
...
f = soup.find(something).find(something)
```

among a,b,c,d,e,f, error can happen anywhere and their code should not be revised.

the variable 'b' is not matter because it would be None, which is ok.

**but variable 'a' or 'f' is problem, because it would end the script.**

i know there is "try - exception" grammar but that's not what i want.
of course it can be written like this:

```
try : 
 a = soup.find(something).find(something)
except Exception:
 a = None
...
try : 
 f = soup.find(something).find(something)
except Exception:
 f = None
```

looks ridiculous, doesnt it?

how can i handle it gracefully?

Comment: The problem is that you are chaining two function call that are not guaranteed to find whatever you need. What I would do is check if it's possible to combine the `soup.find(something).find(something)` into `soup.find(something)`.

Comment: @YacineMahdid you're right. but the second 'find' method has no attribute to distinguished. maybe i need to make it into 2 steps. thank you anyway

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Would breaking this up into two steps solve the problem?

Something like:

```
a = soup.find(something)
if a is not None:
    a = a.find(something)
```

If not, I agree with the `AttributeError` suggestion.

You may find [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/21553327/why-is-except-pass-a-bad-programming-practice) about exception handling interesting/helpful.

Answer (score 0):

I hope this solves your issue here. Just add pass in except statement

```
except:
    pass
```

Comment: FYI--`except: pass` is [considered an anti-pattern](https://realpython.com/the-most-diabolical-python-antipattern/)

Comment: Sorry but that way is not what i want. if error occur while assigning a, then rest variables(b,c,d,e,f) would not be defined, right?

Answer (score 0):

in your case you should use:

```
try:
    f = soup.find(something).find(something)
except AttributeError:
    f = None
```

Comment: but there are several variables should be assigned. sorry but this is not what i want. thanks anyway.

Comment: each exception depend on situation