# How to quit while loop conditionally using Selenium and Python

Tags: python, selenium-webdriver, while-loop, break, nosuchelementexception

i have a while loop, it's working all fine, i just want to make a small modification on the line             `Marks = driver.find_element_by_xpath("HERE")`

i want to make it like this: if `Marks` is not showing then quit loop

```
while len(driver.find_elements_by_xpath("xxxxx']")) != 1:
    try:
        wait.until(EC.visibility_of_element_located((By.XPATH, "xxxxx']")))
        List = driver.find_element_by_xpath("yyyyyyy")
        List.click()
        print('done1')
        time.sleep(2)
        Marks = driver.find_element_by_xpath("HERE")
edit here
        time.sleep(2)
        Marks.click()
        time.sleep(5)
        print('done3')
        driver.get("qqqqqqq")
        driver.find_element_by_xpath('qqqqqqq').click()
        wait.until(EC.visibility_of_element_located((By.XPATH, "qqqqqqq")))
    except:
        pass
```

Answer (score 0):

You can do it with try/except. If Marks is not on the webpage (Python can't find it by XPath) the script will raise an error.

```
try:
  Marks = driver.find_element_by_xpath("HERE")
except:
  quit()
```

Comment: it doesn't find it but it's doesn't show an error, it stay blocked waiting

Comment: even with try/except

Answer (score 0):

From your code block it is not that clear why you want to `pass` within `except`. This means that you are willingly catching any error although you are absolutely not prepared for it and we also you don’t do anything about it.

However, to quit loop when `Marks` is not showing up i.e. resulting into [NoSuchElementException](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/47993443/selenium-selenium-common-exceptions-nosuchelementexception-when-using-chrome/47995294#47995294) you can handle it now in the `except` block as follows:

```
while len(driver.find_elements_by_xpath("xxxxx']")) != 1:
    try:
        wait.until(EC.visibility_of_element_located((By.XPATH, "xxxxx']")))
        List = driver.find_element_by_xpath("yyyyyyy")
        List.click()
        print('done1')
        time.sleep(2)
        Marks = driver.find_element_by_xpath("HERE")
        time.sleep(2)
        Marks.click()
        time.sleep(5)
        print('done3')
        driver.get("qqqqqqq")
        driver.find_element_by_xpath('qqqqqqq').click()
        wait.until(EC.visibility_of_element_located((By.XPATH, "qqqqqqq")))
    except NoSuchElementException:
        break
```

**Note** : You have to add the following import:

```
from selenium.common.exceptions import NoSuchElementException
```

---

### tl; dr

[Why is “except: pass” a bad programming practice?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/21553327/why-is-except-pass-a-bad-programming-practice)