# Skip exceptions in python

Tags: python, python-3.x

I have a newbie questions:
let say I have this list of stock in python

```
import requests

list = ["AMZN","APPL", "BAC"]

try:
    for x in list:
        url ='https://financialmodelingprep.com/api/v3/quote-short/'+x+'?apikey=demo'
        response = requests.request('GET', url)
        result = response.json()
        print(result[0]["price"]) 

except:
    pass
```

the second ticker will throw an exceptions, how do I make python to run the third ticker no matter what happen to the second ticker requests?

Comment: A blanket `except` is almost always a bug. See https://stackoverflow.com/questions/21553327/why-is-except-pass-a-bad-programming-practice

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use `try-except` inside `for` loop like below

```
import requests

list = ["AMZN","APPL", "BAC"]


for x in list:
    try:
        url ='https://financialmodelingprep.com/api/v3/quote-short/'+x+'?apikey=demo'
        response = requests.request('GET', url)
        result = response.json()
        print(result[0]["price"]) 

    except:
       pass
```

Answer (score 0):

You can use `continue`

```
import requests

list = ["AMZN","APPL", "BAC"]

for x in list:
    try:
        url ='https://financialmodelingprep.com/api/v3/quote-short/'+x+'?apikey=demo'
        response = requests.request('GET', url)
        result = response.json()
        print(result[0]["price"])
    except:
        continue
```