# CSV - How to read and write row by row?

Tags: python, python-3.x, csv

I have a CSV file like this:

[image: screenshot of csv file]

In Python 3 I am already parsing price data from URL like this:

```
source1 = "https://www.amazon.com/product1"
source2 = "https://www.ebay.com/product1"
source3 = "https://www.bestbuy.com/product1"
```

Getting Price data like this:

```
result1 = trim.sub('', mystring1)
result2 = trim.sub('', mystring2)
result3 = trim.sub('', mystring3)
```

Now I want to read the above the top CSV file want to feed each row's URL into:

```
source1 = "read.csv"
source2 = "read.csv"
source3 = "read.csv"
```

and update the price column using `result1`, `result2`, and `result3`,
then go to the next row do the same again.

Can anyone help me how to read and write CSV file like this?

I was able to read the CSV list one by one but when I am trying to write to a new file it is writing like the following picture

[image]

Here is the code. It is creating a new row

```
import csv


with open('compare_sheet', 'w', newline='') as csv_file:
    fieldnames = ['ProductName', 'Amazon', 'Ebay', 'BestBuy']
    writer = csv.DictWriter(csv_file, fieldnames=fieldnames)
    writer.writeheader()

    product = pr_name.text
    result1 = trim.sub('', mystring1)
    print(result1)
    writer.writerow({'ProductName': product, 'Amazon': result1})

    result2 = trim.sub('', mystring2)
    print(result2)
    writer.writerow({'Ebay': result2})

    result3 = trim.sub('', mystring3)
    print(result3)
    writer.writerow({'BestBuy': result3})
```

How can I write price on same line?

Comment: Start with the "csv" module and show what you tried if you have problems.

Comment: Thanks for the edits, but we still need to see a [mre]. In your final program, you only write a single row. Can you trim this down to a program where you try to write multiple rows, and also show us what error is being displayed (a traceback?)

Comment: Hello, Can you check now?

Comment: Images of text are still [a nuisance](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/303812/discourage-screenshots-of-code-and-or-errors), but thanks for the update.

Comment: Tangentially `except Exception` is always a bug. See https://stackoverflow.com/questions/21553327/why-is-except-pass-a-bad-programming-practice

Answer (score 0):

Like its name says, `writerow` writes a complete row. You want to assemble all the results into one row, like this;

```py
writer.writerow({'ProductName': product, 'Amazon': result1, 'Ebay': result2, 'BestBuy': result3})
```

Obviously you can only do this when you have populated all three variables.

Comment: I tried it. But then it is only showing one row. When it is going over the loop maybe it is erasing the old row.

Comment: What is "it"? Your code only examines one product so there will only be one output row.

Comment: Oh ... the code you deleted seems to replace the entire CSV file each time you get a new result. You want to append, or better yet only `open` once at the beginning and then keep it open and keep writing until you are done.