# Trying to use the filenotfound error in python open file function

Tags: python, python-3.x

I am making a file open function for the beginning of my program where it prompts the user to input a filename and then it will open that file. I was trying to use the try-except function for this so that if it's a valid file then print it and if its not a valid file to return a filenotfound error. I'm unsure how I can implement the file not found error. This is what I came up with so far:

```
def open_file():
   file = input("Please input a file to use: ")
   try:
       fp = open(file)
   except:
       filenotfounderror
```

I'm pretty sure this should work but I'm not sure what to write in place of the filenotfound error after except

Comment: If the file couldn't be `open`ed, a `FileNotFound` error will be raised alone... You actually don't need to do anything

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This is how it should be:

```
def open_file():
       file = input("Please input a file to use: ")
       try:
           fp = open(file)
       except FileNotFoundError:
         print("File Not Found")
```

Answer (score 0):

I think the below is what you are looking for

```
 def open_file():
   file_name = input("Please input a file to use: ")
   try:
       fp = open(file_name)
       # do something with the file - dont forget to close it
   except FileNotFoundError:
      print(f"Wrong file or file path: {file_name}")
```

Answer (score 0):

You don't need `try`/`except` for this; Python will raise a FileNotFoundError without your help if the file cannot be found.

What your code would do is replace *every other error* (permission denied, invalid file name, wrong moon phase over Redmond, etc) with FileNotFoundError. Don't do that (and generally [don't use a blanket `except`](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/21553327/why-is-except-pass-a-bad-programming-practice), at least until you know exactly what you are doing).

If you want to raise an exception, the keyword for that is `raise`. For example;

```py
try:
    with open(input("File: ")) as inp:
        # ... do something
except FileNotFoundError as exc:
    print("ooops, we got a", exc)
    raise ValueError("Surreptitiously replacing %s" % exc)
```