# Scraping full post Indeed with Selenium

Tags: python, selenium, beautifulsoup, webdriver, selenium-firefoxdriver

I'm trying to make a python scraper code work, but I can't, a little help would be useful, I'm still a beginner. The code runs ok, but it crashes and exports a single job to my csv, which i think it is random and does not give any error.Please, someone with more experience who can help me with some tips.Thanks in advance.

```html
from selenium import webdriver
import pandas as pd 
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup

options = webdriver.FirefoxOptions()
driver = webdriver.Firefox()
driver.maximize_window()


df = pd.DataFrame(columns=["Title","Location","Company","Salary","Sponsored","Description"])

for i in range(25):
    driver.get('https://www.indeed.co.in/jobs?q=artificial%20intelligence&l=India&start='+str(i))
    jobs = []
    driver.implicitly_wait(20)
    

    for job in driver.find_elements_by_class_name('result'):

        soup = BeautifulSoup(job.get_attribute('innerHTML'),'html.parser')
        
        try:
            title = soup.find("a",class_="jobtitle").text.replace("\n","").strip()
            
        except:
            title = 'None'

        try:
            location = soup.find(class_="location").text
        except:
            location = 'None'

        try:
            company = soup.find(class_="company").text.replace("\n","").strip()
        except:
            company = 'None'

        try:
            salary = soup.find(class_="salary").text.replace("\n","").strip()
        except:
            salary = 'None'

        try:
            sponsored = soup.find(class_="sponsoredGray").text
            sponsored = "Sponsored"
        except:
            sponsored = "Organic"
                
        
sum_div = job.find_element_by_class_name('summary')

try:    
              sum_div.click()
except:
             close_button = driver.find_elements_by_class_name('popover-x-button-close')[0]
             close_button.click()
             sum_div.click()            
driver.implicitly_wait(2)
try:            
    job_desc = driver.find_element_by_css_selector('div#vjs-desc').text
    print(job_desc)
except:
    job_desc = 'None'   

df = df.append({'Title':title,'Location':location,"Company":company,"Salary":salary,
                        "Sponsored":sponsored,"Description":job_desc},ignore_index=True)


df.to_csv(r"C:\Users\Desktop\Python\Newtest.csv",index=False)
```

Comment: It seems to be an indentation issue. The code in my answer gave me CSV file with 1931 lines.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It seems to be a simple indentation issue.
A part of your code is running outside of the for loop.

```
from selenium import webdriver
import pandas as pd 
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup

from selenium.webdriver.chrome.options import Options
from selenium import webdriver
from webdriver_manager.chrome import ChromeDriverManager

options = Options()    
driver = webdriver.Chrome(ChromeDriverManager().install(), options=options)


df = pd.DataFrame(columns=["Title","Location","Company","Salary","Sponsored","Description"])

for i in range(0,50,10):
    driver.get('https://www.indeed.co.in/jobs?q=artificial%20intelligence&l=India&start='+str(i))
    jobs = []
    driver.implicitly_wait(20)
    

    for job in driver.find_elements_by_class_name('result'):

        soup = BeautifulSoup(job.get_attribute('innerHTML'),'html.parser')
        
        try:
            title = soup.find("a",class_="jobtitle").text.replace("\n","").strip()
            
        except:
            title = 'None'

        try:
            location = soup.find(class_="location").text
        except:
            location = 'None'

        try:
            company = soup.find(class_="company").text.replace("\n","").strip()
        except:
            company = 'None'

        try:
            salary = soup.find(class_="salary").text.replace("\n","").strip()
        except:
            salary = 'None'

        try:
            sponsored = soup.find(class_="sponsoredGray").text
            sponsored = "Sponsored"
        except:
            sponsored = "Organic"


        sum_div = job.find_element_by_class_name('summary')

        try:    
                    sum_div.click()
        except:
                    close_button = driver.find_elements_by_class_name('popover-x-button-close')[0]
                    close_button.click()
                    sum_div.click()            
        driver.implicitly_wait(2)
        try:            
            job_desc = driver.find_element_by_css_selector('div#vjs-desc').text
            print(job_desc)
        except:
            job_desc = 'None'   

        df = df.append({'Title':title,'Location':location,"Company":company,"Salary":salary,
                                "Sponsored":sponsored,"Description":job_desc},ignore_index=True)

df.to_csv("test.csv",index=False)
```

I use Chrome instead of Firefox but I don't think the issue was there. I just indented your code correctly.

Also, it's not a good idea to put except without an excepted error.
[Why is "except: pass" a bad programming practice?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/21553327/why-is-except-pass-a-bad-programming-practice)

Comment: Thanks for the help, I tried your code in Chrome and it works very well but in Firefox the problem persists. Now give me "TabError: inconsistent use of tabs and spaces in indentation" at the try line:
try
sum_div.click (). I kept changing the spaces but in vain.

Comment: That error means you are using 4 spaces in some places and 1 tab in others. If you look through your code and change all 4 spaces to tabs it will resolve the error.

Comment: @DariusFlorea is this solved your issue or answered your constion please consider marking the answer as accepted. (keep up comunity maintanence)

Comment: I finally solved it. Thanks @Christopher Holder