# How to re-run the code on python after encountering an error?

Tags: python, error-handling

I am using python for a program where it connects with a database. The python program is fairly simple but it can encounter error if there is issue with database. I want to do something like keep running the code on loop until the database issue is gone. How can I achieve it?

Comment: use loop, inside that use try and exception

Answer (score 0):

You can try using try and except.

```
try:
    ---block of code--
except:
    pass
```

You can use something like this or google for more info on the same.

Comment: Hi Vedika,
How is pass working over here? Is it re-running the code in try part, if it encounters an error? My exact requirement is I need to re-run the try part.

Comment: [Why is "except pass" a bad programming practice?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/21553327/why-is-except-pass-a-bad-programming-practice)

Comment: It doesn't re-run the try part for the same sample.  pass is similar to continue. If u want to re-run then i think you should put try part as function and call it again in except in case u encounter an error

Answer (score 0):

Try this

```
while True:
    try:
        #database operation
        break
    except:
        #what to do if an error occurs
```