# Python try-except doesn't work as intended

Tags: python, if-statement, selenium-webdriver, exception, try-catch

I have the following code and for some reason it doesn't quit the browser when the two `elif` statements are triggered OR go to the except part of the code.

The goal is to return False in every case where the "Solved" attribute is not found. I have tried removing the `elif` parts so that it would go to `except` part in all of the other cases but it still doesn't work.

```
while True:
        try:
            sleep(10)
            status = browser.find_element(By.CLASS_NAME, 'status')
            if status.get_attribute("innerHTML") == "Solved":
                break
            elif status.get_attribute("innerHTML") == "Unknown error, watch console":
                browser.quit()
                print("Unknown error - programm ootab 3 minutit...\n")
                sleep(180)
                return False
            elif status.get_attribute("innerHTML") == "Outdated, should be solved again":
                browser.quit()
                print("Captcha outdated - programm ootab 3 minutit...\n")
                sleep(180)
                return False

        except:
            print('Captcha fked up for some reason \n')
            browser.quit()
            return False
```

Comment: What error do you expect thrown by what function that would cause you to go to the `except` clause?

Comment: if the "solved" is not found the it would go to except or if the two other elif statements are found to be present then return false.

Comment: ...that's not what `except` does. `except` lets you handle an exception that was thrown in the `try` block. Are you looking for `else`?

Comment: Based  on the documentation of Selenium, `get_attribute` will not raise any error if the attribute is not found, so there is nothing to be excepted.

Comment: if it doesn't find the "solved" then it doesn't throw exception (sorry if it's a noob question, I don't have that much coding background)?

Comment: Yup, based on Selenium docs: [If there’s no attribute with that name, None is returned.](https://selenium-python.readthedocs.io/api.html#selenium.webdriver.remote.webelement.WebElement.get_attribute)

Comment: So the best solution would be to add "else" statement that returns "false"? As it's automatic captcha solving script then should I also increase the sleep timer from 10 seconds as it would only then check once and if it doesn't find it it gives up, right?

Comment: [Minor nitpick](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/21553327/why-is-except-pass-a-bad-programming-practice): ```except``` without an exception are considered bad practice.