# for every letter in the alphabet list Create a variable to store the frequency of each letter in the string and assign it an initial value of zero

Tags: python

Create a variable to store the given string "You can have data without information, but you cannot have information without data."
Convert the given string to lowercase
Create a list containing every lowercase letter of the English alphabet

for every letter in the alphabet list:
Create a variable to store the frequency of each letter in the string and assign it an initial value of zero
for every letter in the given string:
if the letter in the string is the same as the letter in the alphabet list
increase the value of the frequency variable by one.
if the value of the frequency variable does not equal zero:
print the letter in the alphabet list followed by a colon and the value of the frequency variable

myvar = "You can have data without information, but you cannot have information without data."
print(myvar.lower())
letters = ['a', 'b', 'c', 'd', 'e' , 'f', 'g', 'h', 'i', 'j', 'k', 'l', 'm', 'n', 'o', 'p', 'q', 'r', 's', 't', 'u', 'v', 'w', 'x', 'y', 'z']

I'm stuck on "for every letter in the alphabet list:
Create a variable to store the frequency of each letter in the string and assign it an initial value of zero"

Answer (score 0):

You could use a dictionary:

```
import string

{i: 0 for i in string.ascii_lowercase}
```

Output:

```
{'a': 0, 'b': 0, 'c': 0, 'd': 0, 'e': 0, 'f': 0, 'g': 0, 'h': 0, 'i': 0, 'j': 0, 'k': 0, 'l': 0, 'm': 0, 'n': 0, 'o': 0, 'p': 0, 'q': 0, 'r': 0, 's': 0, 't': 0, 'u': 0, 'v': 0, 'w': 0, 'x': 0, 'y': 0, 'z': 0}
```

Edit:

You could use a [Counter](https://docs.python.org/3/library/collections.html#collections.Counter) to solve this.

Answer (score 0):

Try this to get the count of each character in myvar;

```
import string

dct = {i: 0 for i in string.ascii_lowercase}

myvar = "You can have data without information, but you cannot have information without data."

for i in myvar.lower():
    if i in dct.keys():
        dct[i] = dct[i] + 1
```

Hope this Helps...

Comment: [Why is "except: pass" a bad programming practice?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/21553327/why-is-except-pass-a-bad-programming-practice)

Comment: Thanks @Nin17 ... Edited the code... was not aware of try-except this sort of drawback...