# defining variable in python

Tags: python

I am trying to make a little converter from pdf to word in python, so I have two functions one for converting the file and one to save the file. I wonder how to define a variable in both functions: here what I wrote, `docx_file` is giving me error not defined in the convert function.

```py
def convert():
    try:
        pdf = fileEntry.get()
        cv = Converter(pdf)
        cv.convert(docx_file, start=0, end=None)
        cv.close()
        if docx_file is None:
            return
           
    except FileNotFoundError:
        fileEntry.delete(0,END)
        fileEntry.config(fg="red")
        fileEntry.insert(0,"Please select a pdf file first")
    except:
        pass
    
def save2word():

    docx_file = asksaveasfile(mode='w',defaultextension=".docx", filetypes=[("word file","*.docx"), ("text file","*.txt")])
    docx_file.write()
    docx_file.close()
    
    if docx_file is None:
        return
    
    print("saved")
    fileEntry.delete(0,END)
    fileEntry.insert(0,"pdf Extracted and Saved...")
```

Comment: Please update your question with samples of how the two functions are called.

Comment: Pass whatever variables you need as function parameters.

Comment: `except: pass` is generally [not a good idea](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/21553327/why-is-except-pass-a-bad-programming-practice).

Answer (score 2):

You could try declaring a blank variable

```
docx_file = ""    
def convert():
    try:
        pdf = fileEntry.get()
        cv = Converter(pdf)
        cv.convert(docx_file, start=0, end=None)
        cv.close()
        if docx_file is None:
            return
```

or set the variable to global

```
def convert():
    try:
        pdf = fileEntry.get()
        cv = Converter(pdf)
        cv.convert(docx_file, start=0, end=None)
        cv.close()
        global docx_file
        if docx_file is None:
            return
```

Comment: As a programmer you should try very, *very*, **very** hard not to use globals.

Comment: Thank you all for helping me