# How to catch a package-specific exception?

Tags: python, pandas, exception, pyodbc

When I try to read a table from an SQL database with pandas using `pandas.read_sql`, the package pyodbc throws an `DataError` (pyodbc.DataError) that I would like to catch. The `DataError` is caused by an unexpected nvarchar value, causing an conversion failure when pyodbc attempts to convert it to data type int.

This is my code:

```
import pandas as pd 
import pyodbc
from sqlalchemy import create_engine
from sqlalchemy.engine import URL

driver = "SQL Server"
server = "my_server" 
database = "my_db" 

connection_string = (f"Driver={driver};"
                     f"Server={server};"
                     f"Database={database};"
                     f"Trusted_Connection=yes;"
                     f"TrustServerCertificate=yes")

connection_url = URL.create("mssql+pyodbc", 
                            query={"odbc_connect": connection_string})

engine = create_engine(connection_url)

# select only the first 10 rows in a table 
query = (f"SELECT top 10 * "
         f"FROM abc.table_name")

df = pd.read_sql(sql=query, 
             con=engine)
```

The output is

```
DataError: (pyodbc.DataError) ('22018', "[22018] [Microsoft][ODBC SQL Server Driver][SQL Server]Conversion failed when converting the nvarchar value '00:35' to data type int. (245) (SQLExecDirectW)")
[SQL: SELECT top 10 * FROM abc.table_name]
(Background on this error at: https://sqlalche.me/e/14/9h9h)
```

I know how to [catch and handle](https://wiki.python.org/moin/HandlingExceptions) [built-in exceptions](https://docs.python.org/3/library/exceptions.html) using `try` and `except` statements in Python. The `DataError` (pyodbc.DataError) however is not a built-in exception. I would like to catch this package-specific error while not just catching *any* error (I understand this to be [bad practice](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/21553327/)).

I have attempted the following:

```
try: 
    df = pd.read_sql(sql=query, 
                 con=engine)
except DataError as err: 
    print(err)
    pass
```

This results in an `NameError: name 'DataError' is not defined` (as far as I understand, because `DataError` is not a built-in exception).

I have also attempted the following:

```
try: 
    df = pd.read_sql(sql=query, 
                 con=engine)
except pyodbc.DataError as err: 
    print(err)
    pass
```

This results in `DataError: (pyodbc.DataError)`, because the error is not caught.

Comment: The last snippet caught the exception right?

Comment: You can `print(type(err))` to get the class name of it

Comment: @AbdulNiyasPM The last snippet did not catch the exception, because the class name is incorrect.

Comment: @WaketZheng Yes, thank you! I had not thought of that.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

`DataError` seems to be an exception from SQLalchemy, see documentation: https://docs.sqlalchemy.org/en/20/core/exceptions.html#sqlalchemy.exc.DataError

Try:

```py
from sqlalchemy.exc import DataError
```

then

```py
try:
    df = pd.read_sql(sql=query, 
                 con=engine)
except DataError as err: 
    print(err)
    pass
```

Comment: And `pyodbc.DataError` is printed, because sqlalchemy's DataError is re-raised from it and propagates the message.

Comment: As commented by @WhaketZheng, `print(type(err))` allows to get the correct class name of the exception: `<class 'sqlalchemy.exc.DataError'>`.

Answer (score 1):

You can get the class name of the exception by this way:

```py
try: 
    df = pd.read_sql(sql=query, 
                 con=engine)
except Exception as e: 
    print(type(e))
    raise e
```

And sometimes you may need to use BaseException to catch some special exceptions(such as SystemExit/KeyboardInterrupt)

```py
try:
    do_stuff()
except BaseException as e:
    print(type(e), e)
    raise e
```

Comment: Or `breakpoint()` instead of printing to have a chance to investigate this in real time, if you can attach to the debugger session.