# Python try and except 2

Tags: python

All,

I am learning python and trying to write a code which resolves dns name, if it is not resolved then print it and go next. I have tried except pass and except raise and no result. here is my code. any advice will be appreciated .

code works however if it encounters an error it stops and prints the error does not move on.

```
import socket
#loop use doc named list.txt as input and read it with each line assigned as x value

with open("list.txt", "r") as x:
 try:
  for line in x:
   print  (socket.gethostbyname(line.strip()) + "    "+line)

 except Exception:
   #print("Can't resolve hostname    "+line)
   pass
```

forum and readings loads of try excpet/pass with not avail

Comment: Your `for` loop is inside the `try`. When exception is thrown whole `try` block is exited.

Comment: Indeed: the try except should only encase the `print(socket...)` statement

Comment: Python has a customary indentation by four spaces. Using that might make the structure more readable/understandable and could have made that mistake obvious to you. BTW: Try to find a video tutorial for using a debugger. If you had stepped through the code, you would have probably noticed as well.

Comment: See also [Why is "except: pass" a bad programming practice?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/21553327/why-is-except-pass-a-bad-programming-practice)

Answer (score 1):

You need to wrap the call to gethostbyname in try/except.

Something like this:

```
from socket import gethostbyname, gaierror

for host in map(str.strip, open("list.txt")):
    try:
        print(gethostbyname(host), host)
    except gaierror:
        print("Can't resolve", host)
```

Comment: I'm surprised you didn't close the opened file handle.

Comment: @Jeyekomon The file handle goes out of scope once the *for* loop terminates and will then be closed implicitly

Comment: Thank you and that works beautifully Do you know why using my original code the try and pass didn’t work? Is it not meant to do the same?

Comment: @drifter17a In your code, the try/except was outside the *for* loop which meant that if an exception occurred the *for* loop would break. In this answer, the try/except is within the *for* loop

Comment: @Codist I am not sure I follow. I am new to python and coding however did coding years ago using bash and some other language. From what I can tell, I am doing try and except and my commands are within it so unsure what you means when stating my code is outside of loop.

Comment: The implicit closing sure works in this simple code. I just find it a bad habit.

Comment: @drifter17a In your question the `try` is **before** the `for` keyword. In Codist's answer the `try` is **after** the `for` keyword. Have you noticed?

Comment: Yeah thanks guys