# Python TelegramBot JobQueue not performing return

Tags: python, telegram, telegram-bot, python-telegram-bot

update.message.reply_text works fine but I can't perform the return function because it can't pull context.user_data properly so it keeps sending the same message every 10 seconds

```
async def matching(update: Update, context: CallbackContext):
    async def check_who_likes(context: CallbackContext):

        try:
            conn = connection_pool.get_connection()
            cursor = conn.cursor()
            user_id = update.message.from_user.id
            cursor.execute("SELECT LikeUserID FROM Likes WHERE LikedUserID = %s", (user_id,))
            likes = cursor.fetchall()
            result = len(likes)
            if len(likes) > 0:
                await update.message.reply_text(f"{len(likes)}")
                context.user_data['result'] = True
        except Exception as e:
            pass
        finally:
            cursor.close()
            conn.close()
            await asyncio.sleep(1)


    job = context.job_queue.run_repeating(check_who_likes, interval=10, first=0,data={'result': None})
    await job.run(context.application)
    result = job.data['result']
    if result:
        return SHOW_WHO_LIKES
```

Comment: Please provide enough code so that we can reproduce your problem locally. Also you should not [passe on exceptions](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/21553327).

Comment: I changed the code and description, the previous problem is as we discussed with you in the previous post, the reason why we cannot perform the return is because we need to return in the matching function, but this time the problem is that since the telegrambot library has been updated, I need to use data instead of context, but when I do it with data, the None value as return comes by default, it cannot properly pull the context.user_data['result'] = True value in check_who_likes.

Answer (score 0):

The following corrected code pulls out the data and assigns it as a variable, but the problem with this code is that it performs the operation directly from SHOW_WHO_LIKES and returns to the old matching

Note: In SHOW_WHO_LIKES, only a message is sent to the user, there is no return in it.

```
async def matching(update: Update, context: CallbackContext):
    async def check_who_likes(context: CallbackContext):

        try:
            conn = connection_pool.get_connection()
            cursor = conn.cursor()
            user_id = update.message.from_user.id
            cursor.execute("SELECT LikeUserID FROM Likes WHERE LikedUserID = %s", (user_id,))
            likes = cursor.fetchall()
            result = len(likes)
            if len(likes) > 0:
                await update.message.reply_text(f"{len(likes)}")
                context.job.data = True
        except Exception as e:
            pass
        finally:
            cursor.close()
            conn.close()
            await asyncio.sleep(1)

    job = context.job_queue.run_repeating(check_who_likes, interval=10, first=0, data=None)
    await job.run(context.application)
    result = job.data
    if result:
        return SHOW_WHO_LIKES
```