# Double Progress Bar in Python

Tags: python, progress-bar

Is there a way to create a double progress bar in Python?
I want to run two loops inside each other. For each loop I want to have a progress bar. My program looks like:

```
import time
for i1 in range(5):
    for i2 in range(300):
        # do something, e.g. sleep
        time.sleep(0.01)
        # update upper progress bar
    # update lower progress bar
```

The output somewhere in the middle should look something like

```
50%|############################                                  |ETA: 0:00:02
80%|##################################################            |ETA: 0:00:04
```

The already existing really cool [progressbar](http://code.google.com/p/python-progressbar/) module doesn't seem to support that.

Comment: The above link is broken @ρss

Comment: Related question: [Rewrite multiple lines in the console - Stack Overflow](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6840420).

Answer (score 157, accepted):

Use the [nested progress bars feature of tqdm](https://github.com/tqdm/tqdm#nested-progress-bars), an extremely low overhead, very customisable progress bar library:

```bash
$ pip install -U tqdm
```

Then:

```py
from tqdm import tqdm
# from tqdm.auto import tqdm  # notebook compatible
import time
for i1 in tqdm(range(5)):
    for i2 in tqdm(range(300), leave=False):
        # do something, e.g. sleep
        time.sleep(0.01)
```

(The `leave=False` is optional - needed to discard the nested bars upon completion.)

You can also use `from tqdm import trange` and then replace `tqdm(range(...))` with `trange(...)`. You can also get it [working in a notebook](https://github.com/tqdm/tqdm#ipython-jupyter-integration).

Alternatively if you want just one bar to monitor everything, you can use `tqdm`'s version of `itertools.product`:

```py
from tqdm.contrib import itertools
import time
for i1, i2 in itertools.product(range(5), range(300)):
    # do something, e.g. sleep
    time.sleep(0.01)
```

Comment: It doesn't work. Either because of a bug, either it's not intended to work like that, but it keep adding lines to console.

Comment: I agree with @asu, it doesn't work like OP describes in my console, it just makes loads and loads of new lines

Comment: Yes see https://github.com/tqdm/tqdm/#faq-and-known-issues - essentially if your console doesn't support it then none of the other answers would work either - the only options are to ask maintainers of your console to support carriage return, or to use a different console.

Comment: If you're using Jupyter notebooks, you need to use the notebook submodule: `from tqdm.notebook import tqdm`

Comment: @asu I just added a note about `leave=False` in case that's what you mean

Comment: @casper.dcl - it still doesn't work. Try to run this code on Python 3.7 in console or in jupyter notebook. It's mainly impossible because console doesn't support editing the previous line, like it supports to edit current line under cursor with "carriage return"

Comment: @asu to use this in a notebook you need to uncomment the `tqdm.auto` line. Also modern consoles *do* support editing the previous line.

Comment: @casper.dcl you are right, it works indeed in Notebook, Thank you!
But what do you mean by modern consoles? My modern Ubuntu Server 20 console through SSH doesn't support it, how we can find/identify the modern consoles?

Comment: @asu if you're sshing from windows 7 putty it doesn't matter if the destination is ubuntu server 20

Comment: The from tqdm.auto import tqdm  is working great in notebooks! thanks!

Comment: You'd need to `pip install ipywidgets` before you can use `from tqdm.notebook import tqdm`

Answer (score 61):

I basically just want to add to the answer of @casper.dcl. In the slightly different case, where you have two nested for loops and want just a SINGLE progress bar you can do the following.

```py
from tqdm import tqdm
import time
n = 5
m = 300
with tqdm(total=n * m) as pbar:
    for i1 in tqdm(range(n)):
        for i2 in tqdm(range(m)):
            # do something, e.g. sleep
            time.sleep(0.01)
            pbar.update(1)
```

I know that was not the question, but it might be still helpful for some folks.

Comment: Doesn't work for me ((
line:   with tqdm(total=1000) as pbar:
TypeError: 'module' object is not callable

Comment: I forgot to add "from tqdm import tqdm" in the beginning. Thank you for the answer! this is what i needed

Comment: Nice idea! Added `tqdm.contrib.itertools.product` to my answer :)

Comment: For me, to achieve just one progressbar I had to remove the call to tqdm in the loops. just leave `for i1 in range(n)` for the loops.

Answer (score 15):

Once here was an answer by @yurenchen (which was deleted), that advertised [rich](https://rich.readthedocs.io/en/stable/) library, it has progress bar routines described [here in docs](https://rich.readthedocs.io/en/stable/progress.html#advanced-usage).

**Note**. See also my other two answers in this thread about progress bar - [using enlighten lib](https://stackoverflow.com/a/63796670/941531) and [using ASCII art](https://stackoverflow.com/a/70107184/941531).

Rich library can be installed by `python -m pip install rich`.

Minimal example that shows stack of three progress bars of different colors is:

[Try it online!](https://replit.com/@moytrage/StackOverflow23113494var3#main.py)

```py
import time

from rich.progress import Progress

with Progress() as progress:

    task1 = progress.add_task("[red]Downloading...", total=1000)
    task2 = progress.add_task("[green]Processing...", total=1000)
    task3 = progress.add_task("[cyan]Cooking...", total=1000)

    while not progress.finished:
        progress.update(task1, advance=0.5)
        progress.update(task2, advance=0.3)
        progress.update(task3, advance=0.9)
        time.sleep(0.02)
```

which produces following colorful console output (+ aciinema [link](https://asciinema.org/a/460282)):

[image]

Answer (score 13):

It would require you to move the cursor position. I have written you a hacky thing to do it.

This script relies on the fact that the progressbar module assumes that you are on a fresh line to draw the progress bar. By simply moving the cursor up (using the escape code for "move cursor 1 row up"), and down (just using a newline. I could also use an escape code, but newline is easier and faster), one can maintain multiple progress bars.

```
import progressbar, time, sys

def up():
    # My terminal breaks if we don't flush after the escape-code
    sys.stdout.write('\x1b[1A')
    sys.stdout.flush()

def down():
    # I could use '\x1b[1B' here, but newline is faster and easier
    sys.stdout.write('\n')
    sys.stdout.flush()

# Total bar is at the bottom. Move down to draw it
down()
total = progressbar.ProgressBar(maxval=50)
total.start()

for i in range(1,51):
    # Move back up to prepare for sub-bar
    up()

    # I make a new sub-bar for every iteration, thinking it could be things
    # like "File progress", with total being total file progress.
    sub = progressbar.ProgressBar(maxval=50)
    sub.start()
    for y in range(51):
        sub.update(y)
        time.sleep(0.005)
    sub.finish()

    # Update total - The sub-bar printed a newline on finish, so we already
    # have focus on it
    total.update(i)
total.finish()
```

This is of course a bit hacky, but it gets the job done. I hope that it is useful.

Comment: Thanks, this almost works perfectly!
I just had to insert a `sub.finish()` and `total.finish()` after the loops, otherwise it would not go "down".
Could you insert that in your code?

Comment: I added it. Odd, though, my local version of progressbar did that itself when you reached the max value. Maybe a difference in version? Oh well, you got it working, and that's what matters.

Comment: Hmm, this didn't work for me, but I'm using `with as` statement. Maybe doing on the conventional way, using `start()` and `finish()`, it could work

Comment: Anyone can add a recipe for the same in jupyter notebook? This up/down hack does not work there, kist produces new copies of the bars.

Answer (score 10):

Use [enlighten](https://pypi.org/project/enlighten/):

```
import time
import enlighten

manager = enlighten.get_manager()
ticks = manager.counter(total=100, desc="Ticks", unit="ticks", color="red")
tocks = manager.counter(total=20, desc="Tocks", unit="tocks", color="blue")

for num in range(100):
    time.sleep(0.1)  # Simulate work
    print("The quick brown fox jumps over the lazy dog. {}".format(num))
    ticks.update()
    if not num % 5:
        tocks.update()

manager.stop()
```

[image]

Answer (score 9):

Inspired by [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/60664117/941531), I also tried [enlighten](https://pypi.org/project/enlighten/) python library and wrote my simple helper function `pit()` for wrapping iterators inside for-loop (top of code) and provided example of usage (bottom of code) plus live terminal-screencast.

**Note**. See also my other two answers in this thread about progress bar - [using rich lib](https://stackoverflow.com/a/70611472/941531) and [using ASCII art](https://stackoverflow.com/a/70107184/941531).

Main difference to linked answer is that `pit()` allows to be used inside for-loop to wrap iterator, instead of using manual `.update()` method, this iterator-wrapping functionality is lacking in `englighten`, that's why I decided to implement my own.

As one can see in Accepted answer other famous progress bar libraries like `tqdm` already have this functionality of wrapping iterators in for-loop and also multiple progress bars in nested loops.

Works in color both in Linux and Windows.

[Try it online!](https://replit.com/@moytrage/StackOverflow23113494#main.py)

```py
# Helper Progress Iterator
# Needs: python -m pip install enlighten

def pit(it, *pargs, **nargs):
    import enlighten
    global __pit_man__
    try:
        __pit_man__
    except NameError:
        __pit_man__ = enlighten.get_manager()
    man = __pit_man__
    try:
        it_len = len(it)
    except:
        it_len = None
    try:
        ctr = None
        for i, e in enumerate(it):
            if i == 0:
                ctr = man.counter(*pargs, **{**dict(leave = False, total = it_len), **nargs})
            yield e
            ctr.update()
    finally:
        if ctr is not None:
            ctr.close()


####### Usage Example ########

import time

def Generator(n):
    for i in range(n):
        yield i

for i in pit(range(2), color = 'red'):
    for j in pit(range(3), color = 'green'):
        for k in pit(Generator(4), total = 4, color = 'blue'):
            for l in pit(Generator(5)):
                print(i, j, k, l)
                time.sleep(0.05)
```

Output (+ [ascii-video](https://asciinema.org/a/358430)):

[image: ascii]

Comment: What should be caught from `len(it)`?

Comment: Also, doesn't work (at least not with remote interpreter)

Comment: @Gulzar If you need length of my iterator then use `list`, do `len(list(it))`, e.g. `len(list(pit(Generator(5))))` will give `5`. It doesn't throw anything, but this iterator can't be used second time any more, you have to create new same iterator. In this sence my iterator is not meant to return its length, it is only meant to be iterated in `for` loop. Just now I clicked my link [Try it online!](https://replit.com/@moytrage/StackOverflow23113494#main.py) located before code, it showed same thing as my video above, just click `Run` then in 15 seconds click `Stop` and `Run` again and wait.

Comment: You do `try:`... `except` on `len(it)`. If it doesn't throw anything, then why do it?

Comment: @Gulzar OK, I thought that you have some trouble with my `pit()`. But instead you're asking why I catch exception inside my code of `len(it)`. This happens because not all iterables may return length, some iterables are infinite or they don't know length in advance. For example if you have code `def f(): yield from [1, 2, 3]      print(len(f()))`, then this code throws exception TypeError when counting len, but if you use for loop `for e in f(): pass` then it works perfectly well.

Comment: @Gulzar TypeError is not the only type of exception that is thrown by `len(it)`. That's why I just wrote `except:`. So it is wrong, against my design, that you modified my code to `except TypeError:`. If you want to exclude KeyboardInterrupt, then just write `except Exception:`, which will catch ANY exception, but definitely not TypeError as you did.

Comment: Catching ALL exceptions is also wrong, and is the reason I asked the very simple question: "What should be caught from len(it)?". If it is `TypeError` and something else, catch ONLY them.

Comment: @Gulzar The reason for catching ALL exceptions is following. I'm doing the same way as human concludes `if length can't be retrieved then we'll make our iterator as having no length too`. And here `length can't be retrieved` means simply that I have to catch anything. Any exception would mean that length CAN'T be retrieved. What if author of that iterator has implemented his own exception, not necessary TypeError. I can't predict what exception exactly would be thrown by some custom User Iterator. Hence I can't tell that catching only TypeError is correct way.

Comment: You are implying some degenerate implementation of a class having `def __len__(self): raise MyException()`. This makes absolutely no sense, and should be raised and not silently caught. Maybe `AttributeError` can be thrown as well, in which case, again, catching it silently makes no sense. [Silencing exceptions is bad practice](https://stackoverflow.com/a/2416334/913098) [also this](https://stackoverflow.com/a/10594142/913098), especially in library functions

Answer (score 7):

A little late in the game, but here's an answer using nothing but tqdm

```
import re
from time import sleep
from tqdm import trange

class DescStr:
    def __init__(self):
        self._desc = ''

    def write(self, instr):
        self._desc += re.sub('\n|\x1b.*|\r', '', instr)

    def read(self):
        ret = self._desc
        self._desc = ''
        return ret

    def flush(self):
        pass


rng_a = trange(10)
desc = DescStr()
for x in rng_a:
    for y in trange(10, file=desc, desc="Y"):
        rng_a.set_description(desc.read())
        sleep(0.1)
```

which yields:

```
Y:  90%|######### | 9/10 [00:00<00:00,  9.55it/s]: 100%|##########| 10/10 [00:10<00:00,
```

Comment: Can you explain this? Not the most readable of codes. What is `"Y"`? what does `Desc` stand for? When is `write` called? what is `instr`?

Comment: two loops, one for x, one for y. desc is an abbreviation for description

Comment: this still doesn't explain how this works

Answer (score 5):

Here is a simple method that displays progress for an outer and an inner loop:

```
from tqdm import tqdm
from time import sleep

pbar = tqdm(range(10))
for i in pbar:
    for j in range(20):
        pbar.set_postfix({'inner': j})
        sleep(.2)
```

It's not exactly what you asked for: The inner loop here is only displayed as incrementing numbers, while the progress bar shows the outer loop progress. But it's a useful visualization of nested loops.

Here is a snapshot:

```
 30%|███       | 3/10 [00:14<00:33,  4.77s/it, inner=12]
```

The "inner" counter increments constantly as the progress bar for the outer loop advances slowly.

**Update:**

You can combine this solution with dominecf's solution. The following uses tqdm for the outer loop and integrates an inner loop using dominecf's function (with minor modifications):

```
import tqdm
import time

def myprogress(curr, N, width=10, bars = u'▉▊▋▌▍▎▏ '[::-1],
               full='█', empty=' '): 
    p = curr / N 
    nfull = int(p * width)
    return "{:>3.0%} |{}{}{}| {:>2}/{}"\
        .format(p, full * nfull,
                bars[int(len(bars) * ((p * width) % 1))],
                empty * (width - nfull - 1),
                curr, N)


pbar = tqdm.tqdm(range(10),
                 bar_format='{l_bar}{bar:10}{r_bar}{bar:-10b}')
for i in pbar:
    for j in range(20):
        pbar.set_postfix_str(myprogress(j, 20))
        time.sleep(.2)
```

Here is a snapshot:

```
 30%|███       | 3/10 [00:14<00:34,  4.90s/it, 60% |██████    | 12/20]
```

Answer (score 5):

Inspired by simplicity of [answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/69973866/941531) of @dominecf, just for fun I implemented a helper wrapper function `pbiter()` that can be used in loops to show progress for any iterables. `pbiter()` uses @dominecf's implementation of `myprogress()`.

**Note**. See also my other two answers in this thread about progress bar - [using enlighten](https://stackoverflow.com/a/63796670/941531) and [using rich lib](https://stackoverflow.com/a/70611472/941531).

Don't judge this answer too much, it is only for hackery fun of implementing progress from scratch in pure Python, this answer is not meant to be used in any production environment, use `tqdm` or `enlighten` modules in real application for doing progress.

See my other [answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/63796670/941531) to same Question, that answer shows how to use `enlighten` module for progress.

`pbiter()` from this answer can be very simply used with any iterables in nested loops like following:

```py
for a in pbiter(range(12)):
    for b in pbiter(generator_nums(13)):
        for c in pbiter(generator_nums(7), total = 7):
            time.sleep(0.03)
```

Progress bar total length is figured out either by `len(it)` if it is available for iterable (e.g. for `range(start, stop, step)` it is always available), or by providing `total = ...` param, otherwise progress decays exponentially with multiplier `0.1` (which shows a nice approximation). In three example nested loops above second loop has this exponential behaviour.

Full code below. See ascii-video located after code.

[Try it online!](https://replit.com/@moytrage/StackOverflow23113494var2#main.py)

```py
def myprogress(current, whole=1, n=30, bars=u'▕▏▎▍▌▋▊▉', full='▉', empty='▕'): 
    """ current and whole can be an element of a list being iterated, or just two numbers """
    p = (whole.index(current))/len(whole)+1e-9 if type(whole)==list else current/whole+1e-9 
    return f"{full*int(p*n)}{bars[int(len(bars)*((p*n)%1))]}{empty*int((1-p)*n)} {p*100:>6.2f}%" 

def pbiter(it, *, total = None, width = 36, _cfg = {'idx': -1, 'pbs': {}, 'lline': 0}):
    try:
        total = total or len(it)
    except:
        total = None
    
    _cfg['idx'] += 1
    idx = _cfg['idx']
    pbs = _cfg['pbs']
    pbs[idx] = [0, total, 0]
    
    def Show():
        line2 = ' '.join([
            myprogress(e[1][0], max(e[1][0], e[1][1] or
                max(1, e[1][0]) / max(.1, e[1][2])), width // len(pbs))
            for e in sorted(pbs.items(), key = lambda e: e[0])
        ])
        line = line2 + ' ' * (max(0, _cfg['lline'] - len(line2)) + 0)
        print(line, end = '\r', flush = True)
        _cfg['lline'] = len(line2)
    
    try:
        Show()
        for e in it:
            yield e
            pbs[idx][0] += 1
            pbs[idx][2] += (1. - pbs[idx][2]) * .1
            Show()
        pbs[idx][2] = 1.
        Show()
    finally:
        del pbs[idx]

def test():
    import time

    def generator_nums(cnt):
        for i in range(cnt):
            yield i

    for a in pbiter(range(12)):
        for b in pbiter(generator_nums(13)):
            for c in pbiter(generator_nums(7), total = 7):
                time.sleep(0.03)

test()
```

ASCII-video output (see also asciinema [video page](https://asciinema.org/a/451404)):

[image]

If for some reason you don't have loops and still want to use my `pbiter()`, then you can use it through regular built-in [next()](https://docs.python.org/3/library/functions.html#next) operation, as following:

```py
# Create 3 progress bars, they are at 0% point now
a = pbiter(range(5))
b = pbiter(range(4))
c = pbiter(range(3))
# Some lines of code later, advance progress "a"
next(a)
# And later ...
next(b)
# And later ...
next(b)
# Later ...
next(a); next(c)
# Later ...
next(c); next(b)
```

in other words you can create and advance progress bars manually in any order and at any place of code.

Comment: A bit hard to read for me, but nice. And pertinent to the OP's question: I guess nested iterations make 99 % of use cases for multiple progress bars.

Comment: @dominecf Thanks for up-voting! :) If for some reason you don't have loops, then still you can use even my solution by just creating 3 progress bars without loops like `a = pbiter(range(5)); b = pbiter(range(4)); c = pbiter(range(3))` and then manually advancing them in any order and at any place of code by regular `next()`, like following `next(a); next(b); next(c); next(c); next(b); next(c)`.

Comment: Vote to make this a python package.

Answer (score 4):

I sketched up a standalone, simple progressbar for Python3.6+. No tqdm, no other dependencies, no hacks.

```
def myprogress(current, whole=1, n=30, bars=u'▕▏▎▍▌▋▊▉', full='▉', empty='▕'): 
    """ current and whole can be an element of a list being iterated, or just two numbers """
    p = (whole.index(current))/len(whole)+1e-9 if type(whole)==list else current/whole+1e-9 
    return f"{full*int(p*n)}{bars[int(len(bars)*((p*n)%1))]}{empty*int((1-p)*n)} {p*100:04.1f}%"
```

In pure Python it is hard to re-write more than the last line.
But you can just stack two bars next to each other. (A single-line solution also nicely works e.g. with window decoration in a GUI!)

```
for x in range(300):  ## accepting numerical value
     print(myprogress(x/300), ' '*5, myprogress(x/321), end='\r')
     for busyloop in range(10**5): pass
```

It computes the progress either as ratio of two numbers, or finds an element in a list being iterated. (If you iterate a numpy.array, it is easy to convert it to a list.) So this is also possible:

```
l = ['apples', 'bananas', 'cherries', 'durians']  ## accepting an element from list being iterated
for x in l: 
     print(myprogress(x, whole=l), ' '*5, myprogress(x, whole=l), end='\r')
     for busyloop in range(10**7): pass
```

In the first example you get:

```
▉▉▉▉▉▉▉▉▉▉▉▉▉▉▉▉▉▉▉▉▉▎▕▕▕▕▕▕▕▕ 71.0%      ▉▉▉▉▉▉▉▉▉▉▉▉▉▉▉▉▉▉▉▉▕▕▕▕▕▕▕▕▕▕ 66.4%
```

It's so simple it must be public domain.

PS: if you like Pacman, you may revert the progress right to left and use: bars='ᗦᗠᗦᗠᗦᗠ'

Comment: Nice solution, up-voted! Would be really great if you modify code of your `myprogress()` function so that it REALLY has no dependencies. Now it depends on Numpy as it uses `np.where()`. It is very easy to implement this np.where() in pure Python. So would be great if your progress bar will have only Pure python code without external modules.

Comment: @Arty all fixed, thanks!

Comment: Thanks for fixing! I decided to use your very simple `myprogress()` to create wrapping function `pbiter()` that can wrap any iterable and can be used to automatically show progress in any nested loops. See [my answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/70107184/941531), it has your and mine full code together with details and ASCII video as an example.

Comment: Thanks @dominecf for this solution. up-voted. I like solutions with no dependencies
Any way we can have the progress bars one above the other?

Comment: Yes, @Kenny's solution seems to provide multi-column rewrite.  I am not sure about its compatibility with all terminals, but it looks good. Just modify the above ```print``` command to get the format you desire.

Comment: @nurub You can do two line solution like [in this example](https://replit.com/@moytrage/StackOverflow23113494eg0#main.py) using dominecf's `myprogress()`, main idea is just to use `'\x1b[1A'` ascii sequence to move cursor one line up.

Comment: Kenny's solution uses progressbar library. I wanted a solution without any dependencies. Thanks anyway. 
@Arty, the example in the link you shared also uses a library. I tried to use '\x1b[1A' ASCII code to move the cursor one line up but didn't work. WIth this simple code 
print( 'AAAAAA' )
print( '\x1b[1A' )
print( 'BBBB' )
I'm getting this output
AAAAAA
[1A
BBBB
Thanks anyway

Comment: @nurub I used `colorama` library just to make it work on Windows. You don't need this library at all, just delete colorama import and it will work. BTW, do you need Windows or Linux solution? If Windows solution then not all windows consoles support this Move-Line-Up character. But Linux consoles support it natively. If this move-line-up doesn't work for you, right now I don't know any other ways how to do two lines.

Comment: @Arty I missed your post. I just checked it out and up-voted it. Thanks

Comment: @nurub Thanks for up-voting my post! If you need you can make comments under my post (not here) if they are related to that post.

Answer (score 3):

This can be easily done with [*atpbar*](https://github.com/alphatwirl/atpbar).

For example:

```py
import time, random
from atpbar import atpbar

for i in atpbar(range(4), name='outer'):
    n = random.randint(1000, 10000)
    for j in atpbar(range(n), name='inner {}'.format(i)):
        time.sleep(0.0001)
```

The code above has nested `for` loops. The outer loop iterates four times. For each iteration of the outer loop, the inner loop iterates the number of times that is randomly selected. The progress bar for the inner loop moves up as the loop completes. The active progress bars stay at the bottom. A snapshot of progress bars might look like

```
 100.00% :::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::: |     3287 /     3287 |:  inner 0
 100.00% :::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::: |     5850 /     5850 |:  inner 1
  50.00% ::::::::::::::::::::                     |        2 /        4 |:  outer  
  34.42% :::::::::::::                            |     1559 /     4529 |:  inner 2
```