# how to make a list of tuples from a file in python

Tags: python, tuples, knapsack-problem

Ok I have a file like that looks like this.

```
panite,1,1800
ruby,2,100
diamond,0.75,900
emerald,3,250
amethyst,2,50
opal,1,300
sapphire,0.5,750
benitoite,1,2000
malachite,1,60
```

Our teacher gave us code that uses a try/except to help us open the file. I need to open the file and read each line and make each line a tuple and then put it in a list. The list is supposed to be the last numbe divided by the middle number, and then that value followed by the name of the gem(the middle number is the carat of the gem). The problem i'm having is I cant even get it to make a list from the file. This is what i've tried to open it without much success.

```
def main():
    fileFound = False
    while not fileFound:
        fileName = input('File name containing jewel data: ')
        try:
            dataFile = open(fileName, "r")
            fileFound = True
            knapsack()
        except:
            print ('Could not find that file -- try again')

def knapsack():
    list = dataFile.readline()
```

I've actually had a little success when I changed it to a simple printstatement under def knapsack() where it will print something simple like 2+2, but when I try to make a list, it gives me the except error instead. This is my first programming class so any insight into this would be appreciated.

Comment: Thanks I noticed after I posted it but you fixed it for me before I figured it out. Thank you!

Comment: try list = dataFile.readlines(). readline() only return one line; readlines() return a list of lines.

Answer (score 1):

```
def make_jewel(line):
    name, carats, price = line.split(",")
    return (float(price)/float(carats), name)

def main():
    while True:
        file_name = input('File name containing jewel data: ')
        try:
            with open(file_name) as inf:
                data = [make_jewel(line) for line in inf]
            break
        except FileNotFoundError:
            print('Could not find that file -- try again')

main()
```

and some comments:

- `except:` without a specified exception-type, also known as a "bare exception", is frowned on because it catches *everything*. You should specify the type of exceptions you expect to see, and only handle those; if you catch everything and something totally unexpected fails (ie `ComputerOnFireError` !) you will never find out about it.
- opening a file using `with` is preferred because it ensures the file will always get closed properly.
- when you open a file in text mode, you can iterate over it line-by-line; this is the most common way to process a file.
- when you `.split()` a string, you get a list of strings back. Before doing math on the pieces you have to convert them from a string to a numeric value using `int()` or `float()`.

Hope that helps.

Comment: I think your code should work, but I just want point out you should let him do his homework

Answer (score 0):

Use the [csv](https://docs.python.org/2/library/csv.html) module to read lines as csv rows.

```
import csv

def knapsack(datafile):
    output_data = []
    csv_reader = csv.reader(datafile, delimiter=',')
    for row in csv_reader:
        output_data.append(tuple(row))
    return output_data
```

This will give you `output_data` as:

```
[('panite', '1', '1800'),
 ('ruby', '2', '100'),
 ('diamond', '0.75', '900'),
 ('emerald', '3', '250'),
 ('amethyst', '2', '50'),
 ('opal', '1', '300'),
 ('sapphire', '0.5', '750'),
 ('benitoite', '1', '2000'),
 ('malachite', '1', '60')]
```

which is a list of tuples. This solves your problem of making a list from the file. Now, you should do:

- The numerals in the tuples are strings. You need to make sure [you convert them to `int`](https://docs.python.org/2/library/functions.html#int) before you do the arithmetic operations as you mention in your description.
- Pass `output_data` as an argument to a separate function that does the arithmetic functions you mentioned in your question. This function should build your output list.

A few remarks on your code:

- You define the file handle in the main function, but do not pass it
  to the `knapsack` function. But you reference it in the knapsack
  function which will not give you what you want. So you need to pass
  the `datafile` file handle as argument to your `knapsack` function. You do this by replacing this line in your `main` method from:

  ```
  knapsack()
  ```

  to

  ```
  knapsack(datafile)
  ```
- `list` is the name of a built in type in Python. So it is wise not to use it as the name of a variable in your code.

Comment: So how do I pass it to the knapsack function?

Answer (score 0):

You should:

- send `dataFile` to your `knapsack` function.
- change from `except` to `except IOError` to avoid catching exceptions you *do* want to see.
- close the file (consider using `with` to open the file to avoid having to close it explicitly

  ```
  try:
      dataFile = open(fileName, "r")
      fileFound = True
      knapsack(dataFile)
      dataFile.close()
  except IOError:
      print ('Could not find that file -- try again')
  ```

If you had used `except IOError` from the start of, you would have seen this error:

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  ...
  ...
NameError: global name 'dataFile' is not defined
```

`knapsack` does not know what `dataFile` is, hence the error. **Always** catch *specific* exceptions when using `try..except`. If you don't know which error is thrown - reproduce it before you write the code in the python interpreter (e.g try to open a file that doesn't exists, and notice that `IOError` is thrown).

In `knapsack` you need to change from `readline` to `readlines`.

```
def knapsack(dataFile):
    list = dataFile.readlines()
```

You should also consider to use the [`csv`](https://docs.python.org/2/library/csv.html) module as mentioned in the other answer to handle the data.

Comment: ... the error `global name 'dataFile' is not defined` occurs in Python 2.x because the `input` function tries to evaluate the input-string as a Python expression; use `raw_input` instead. In Python 3.x you will not get that error.

Comment: @HughBothwell No, it doesn't. Look at the `knapsack` function - `dataFile` isn't defined, hence a `nameError` is thrown.

Answer (score 0):

If I understand your question correctly, the exception is because `dataFile` variable is not found inside the `knapsack` function. I'd suggest learning **scoping rules** in Python or read [this](http://my.safaribooksonline.com/book/programming/python/1565924649/functions/ch04-28758) excellent to-the-point chapter on the topic (or search for this topic on the Web!).

The other thing I'd recommend is **not to handle all exceptions** as you've shown in your snippet. [Here's why](https://stackoverflow.com/a/10594142).

The fixed code could look something like this:

```
def main():
    fileFound = False
    while not fileFound:
        fileName = raw_input('File name containing jewel data: ')
        try:
            dataFile = open(fileName, "r")
            fileFound = True
            knapsack(dataFile)
        except IOError:
            print ('Could not find that file -- try again')

def knapsack(dataFile):
    list = dataFile.readline() ### Or you want `readlines()` ?
    print list ### Print to let you know that it works
    # return list ### ???

if __name__ == '__main__':
    main()
```

Answer (score 0):

I would go with something more Pythonic using [list comprehensions](https://docs.python.org/2/tutorial/datastructures.html#list-comprehensions)

```
def knapsack(dataFile):
    with open(dataFile, 'r') as fp:
        lines = [line.strip() for line in fp]

    data = [tuple(line.split(',')) for line in lines]

    return data
```

Where you are passing to your knapsack function the path to your file.