# How to catch all exceptions in Try/Catch Block Python?

Tags: python, python-3.x, python-2.7, exception, subprocess

I am writing python code to install all the library packages required by my program in the linux environment.So the linux may contain python 2.7 or 2.6 or both so I have developed a try and except block codes that will install pip packages in linux. Try block code consists of python 2.7 version pip install and Catch block contains python 2.6 version pip install. My Problem is the peace of code is working fine, when i tried to install pandas in python 2.6 its getting me some errror. I want to catch that exception. Can you please tell me how to improve my try except blocks to catch that exception

```
required_libraries = ['pytz','requests','pandas']
try:
   from subprocess import check_output
   pip27_path = subprocess.check_output(['sudo','find','/','-name','pip2.7'])
   lib_installs = [subprocess.call((['sudo',pip27_path.replace('\n',''),'install', i])) for i in required_libraries]
except:
   p = subprocess.Popen(['sudo','find','/','-name','pip2.6'], stdout=subprocess.PIPE);pip26_path, err = p.communicate()
   lib_installs = [subprocess.call((['sudo',pip26_path.replace('\n',''),'install', i])) for i in required_libraries]
```

Comment: Put another try: except: block inside the except you already have?

Comment: @ChrisCharles Just now i tried the same one. still not catching the exception

Comment: @ChrisCharles 
       except:
  try:
      p = subprocess.Popen(['sudo','find','/','-name','pip2.6'], stdout=subprocess.PIPE);pip26_path, err = p.communicate()
    lib_installs = [subprocess.call((['sudo',pip26_path.replace('\n',''),'install', i])) for i in required_libraries]
          except Exception as e:
    logging.info("error in pip_installs function '%s'" %e)

Comment: Catching all exceptions is often a terrible idea. See https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10594113/bad-idea-to-catch-all-exceptions-in-python

Answer (score 19):

You can catch several exceptions using one block. Let's use Exception and ArithmeticError for exceptions.

```
try:
    # Do something
    print(q)

# Catch exceptions  
except (Exception, ArithmeticError) as e:
    template = "An exception of type {0} occurred. Arguments:\n{1!r}"
    message = template.format(type(e).__name__, e.args)
    print (message)
```

If you need to catch several exceptions and handle each one on its own then you'd write an except statement for each one.

```
try:
    # Do something
    print(q)

# Catch exceptions  
except Exception as e:
    print (1)

except ArithmeticError as e:
    print (2)

# Code to be executed if the try clause succeeded with no errors or no return/continue/break statement

else:
    print (3)
```

You can also check if the exception is of type "MyCustomException" for example using if statements.

```
if isinstance(e, MyCustomException):
    # Do something
    print(1)
```

As for your problem, I suggest splitting the code into two functions.

```
install(required_libraries)

def install(required_libraries, version='pip2.7'):
    # Perform installation
    try:
        from subprocess import check_output
        pip27_path = subprocess.check_output(['sudo','find','/','-name', version])
        lib_installs = [subprocess.call((['sudo',pip27_path.replace('\n',''),'install', i])) for i in required_libraries]

    except Exception as e:
        backup(required_libraries)

def backup(required_libraries, version='pip2.6'):
    try:
        p = subprocess.Popen(['sudo','find','/','-name',version]], stdout=subprocess.PIPE);pip26_path, err = p.communicate()
        lib_installs = [subprocess.call((['sudo',pip26_path.replace('\n',''),'install', i])) for i in required_libraries]

    except Exception as e:
        template = "An exception of type {0} occurred. Arguments:\n{1!r}"
        message = template.format(type(e).__name__, e.args)
        print (message)

        #Handle exception
```

Note: I didn't test this, I'm no expert as well so I hope I can help.

Useful links:

1. [Built-in Exceptions](https://docs.python.org/2/library/exceptions.html)
2. [Errors and Exceptions](https://docs.python.org/3/tutorial/errors.html)
3. [Compound statements](https://docs.python.org/2/reference/compound_stmts.html?highlight=try%20except#the-try-statement)

Comment: Thank you so  much for the reply. I will check which one will be best suited for the code.

Comment: @Rahul please accept the answer if my suggestion works! Good luck!

Comment: @sure i will do that

Comment: The comment *"If it's an exception but it's none of the above"* in the second code block regarding the purpose of 'else' in a try-except-else block is not correct. In fact, the code within the 'else' suite is executed only if no exception whatsoever was raised in 'try'. See the [Python docs](https://docs.python.org/2/reference/compound_stmts.html?highlight=try%20except#the-try-statement): "The optional else clause is executed if the control flow leaves the try suite, no exception was raised, and no return, continue, or break statement was executed."

Comment: @MattP thanks for the clarifications, updated my post

Comment: `except Exception as e:` does not actually catch everything