# do_POST executed more than once when there's an exception

Tags: python, sqlite, http, sqlalchemy

I'm building a simple web app using Python as part of an online course, currently I'm trying to implement some CRUD operations. This app is a simple restaurant menu server that connects to an SQLite database (using SQLAlchemy) and executes some CRUD operations on it.

Part of the app serves a simple html form to modify a restaurant name (using `POST` method), when implementing this operation, an error causes the server to return an empty response, and when looking at the log, no `POST` request was issued and the `do_POST` body was executed 3 times.

Here's the body of the `do_POST` method.

```
def do_POST(self):
    try:
        if self.path.endswith(....):
            (.....)

        if self.path.endswith('/edit'):
            print('inside post ' + self.path) # debugging message
            ctype, pdict = cgi.parse_header(self.headers.getheader('content-type'))
            if ctype == 'multipart/form-data':
                fields = cgi.parse_multipart(self.rfile, pdict)
                messageContent = fields.get('newRestaurantName')


            r_id = self.path.split('/')[2]                
            # if I remove .one() from the instruction bellow, the error goes away.
            # 'session' is an SQLAlchemy DBSession defined above.
            restaurant = session.query(Restaurant).get(r_id).one()             

            restaurant.name = messageContent[0]
            session.add(restaurant)
            session.commit()

            self.send_response(301)
            self.send_header('Content-type', 'text/html')
            self.send_header('Location', '/restaurants')
            self.end_headers()
            return
    except:
        (....)
```

And this is the server output when trying to perform the POST method.

```
Server running at port 8080
10.0.2.2 - - [25/Oct/2018 23:17:27] "GET /restaurants HTTP/1.1" 200 -
10.0.2.2 - - [25/Oct/2018 23:17:30] "GET /restaurants/1/edit HTTP/1.1" 200 -
inside post /restaurants/1/edit
inside post /restaurants/1/edit
inside post /restaurants/1/edit
```

After removing the `.one()` from the query expression, the operation executes without issues.

What I'm trying to understand is why I'm having the debugging message printed three times ! whereas I only performed one (unsuccessful) POST request ? Even if there was an exception, shouldn't the do_POST function only execute once ?

(the server is running from inside a Vagrant VM)

Thank you !

Comment: It doesn’t make sense to call `.one()` on `.get()` as `get()` either returns an instance or `None`. As you say, that fixes the issue so perhaps the bare `except` is the real problem?

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10594113/bad-idea-to-catch-all-exceptions-in-python

Comment: Yes, I understand the issue with `.one()` and I have deleted it in subsequent code. However I do not understand how one exception may cause a function body to be executed 3 times ? can you explain this behavior ? Thanks.

Comment: Given that the issue doesn't occur when you properly use the `get()` method, that leads me to believe that the issue is in your exception handling which you haven't included in the question, making it impossible to answer your follow up question. See [MCVE](https://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve).