# Problem with Recursive Exception to Send Continuous Email Notification in Python

Tags: python, email, recursion, exception, exit

I'm trying to make an exception that will call itself if it catch an exception. The goal is to send notification email without interruption due to errors from the server. But I got stuck with stack overflow first due to too many recursion happening when the email sent reached the daily send quota, so I went around it by not sending after the quota was exceeded. Then another problem arise when other types of exception are caught. somehow the program exited after it successfully send an email after a few recursion due to temporary server error.
here's the exception I made :

```
try:
        mailObj.login(sender, pw)
        mailObj.sendmail(sender, receiver, emailText.as_string())
    except Exception as e:
        print ("fail to send email. error : ", e)
        if str(e).find("Daily user sending quota exceeded") == -1 :
            print("not send quota exceeded, retrying in 5")
            time.sleep(5)
            send_mail(body)
    else :
        print("mail sent")
```

And here's the CMD screenshot of what happened when it suddenly exit :
[image: Recursive exception stop the program and dump all exception called]you  can see that it just suddenly exited the program when the email is sent after several recursion

What I want to achieve is a continuous notification-email-sending function in python. Using this Recursive exception is the way I know how to do it. it sure is better if your solution can solve this problem, but feel free to share your way of sending continuous email without interruption if you know a better way.

Comment: always put code, data and full error message as text (not screenshot, not link) in question (not in comment).  It will be more readable and easier to use in answer, and more people will see it - so more people can help you.

Comment: do you run `send_mail()` inside `send_mail()` ? It is recursion. Don't do this but run in some `while`-loop and exit when it send correctly. OR use `for`-loop to try send mail only few times and resign after ie. 3 tries.

Comment: yeah, i should've just use loop rather than recursion

Answer (score 1):

In the first place, you should always avoid catching all the Exceptions in your program, it sure may seem the easy way, but it can cause you many problems when executing or debugging your code

[see this post for more details](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10594113/bad-idea-to-catch-all-exceptions-in-python)

In your case, you should treat your exceptions in 2 separate except blocs, since clearly you have 2 different type of exceptions

- The first one if the send quota is exceeded
- For the second exception, you should be more specific with the type of exception you want to catch, not only it's a better practice, but you can track what went wrong in your program more easily

and the second
your code will look something like this:

```
try:
    mailObj.login(sender, pw)
    mailObj.sendmail(sender, receiver, emailText.as_string())
except DailyUserQuota as e:
    print("fail to send email. error : ", e)
except TheOtherExceptionYouExpecting as e:
    print("fail to send email. error : ", e)
    print("not send quota exceeded, retrying in 5")
    time.sleep(5)
    # sending the email again
else :
    print("mail sent")
```

Now with this out of the way, catching the exceptions outside send_mail() function should fix your error (at least it will make it easier to debug), so instead of using a recursion try to use a loop, like this for exemple:

```py
sending_email = True
while sending_email:
    try:
        send_mail(body)
    except DailyUserQuota as e:
        print("fail to send email. error : ", e)
        sending_email = False
    except TheOtherExceptionYouExpecting as e:
        print("fail to send email. error : ", e)
        print("not send quota exceeded, retrying in 5")
        time.sleep(5) # trying to send the email again after 5 seconds
    else :
        sending_email = False
        print("mail sent")
```

This code will basically do the same thing your code does but without the recursion and without raising Exceptions inside your except block, which is never a good thing.

In a final note, you should avoid posting images in your posts for codes, error messages, logs etc. [refer to this post to understand why](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/285551/why-should-i-not-upload-images-of-code-errors-when-asking-a-question)

Comment: thank you for the answer. I really should've use loop, eh? but the problem with catching a specific exception in this case is that I don't know every exception that I might find as the exception come from the server-side rather than an inside error. should I just redo it for every exception I found?

Comment: The Server-side should have a documentation containing the potential exceptions for every function, if you're using a public API it certainly has but if it's not the case you can use Exception even if it's a bad practice, but you should separate the exception you know from Exception anyway in my opinion

Comment: so far, the exception i had encountered are "connection error", "temporary server error", and "daily quota exceeded". the first two are solved naturally with a bit of time and I want it to retry sending the email until it's fixed. but I want to skip the last one as it can last more than half a day

Comment: I see, well if you think there aren't any more exception you can do only these 3, but if you really need your program to start working after an unexpected behavior add the Exception block (as the last one, after the 3 known exception)

Comment: But keep in mind that most of the time your program stopping after an unexpected behavior is better than your program catching an unknown exception and continuing the execution like nothing happen, because the later can cause your code to behave in unexpected way