# Openpyxl: Can't write part of string into excel (ValueError)

Tags: python, excel, openpyxl, valueerror

So i created a list `signal` containing numbers and strings which i want to write into an excel sheet. Therefore im using the following for loop:

```
columns = list(string.ascii_uppercase)[:26]
row = 3
for j in range(len(columns)):
    ws[columns[j] + str(row)] = a[j]
row += 1
```

I create the list `a` and write each data into a own column of a `row`. Then i update the `row` for the next list.
My problem now is, when i created the code everything worked fine but now i always get the same error in some files: `ValueError: Cannot convert 'THE-DATA' to Excel`. This string is only a part of the whole string and even if i change the `-` to `_` i will get an error. But if i create an test code i also have no problems with writing everything into an excel sheet. Has anyone an idea why i could get this error message after changing nothing in the code?

Test code (only writing one list into the excel sheet):

```
columns = list(string.ascii_uppercase)[:6]
a_test = [1, 3, "sa", "ABC DEF THE-DATA",7,3]
row = 3  # starting row of the Excel sheet

for j in range(len(columns)):
    ws[columns[j] + str(row)] = a_test[j]

wb.save(fr"Test121314.xlsx")
```

Comment: Have you checked what the object type is of the `a[j]` value that is triggering the error using a debugging mode?

Comment: Its type is a string, thats why i don't really get why the error refers to only a part of the string.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I'm not sure what the problem is exactly, but you are trying to populate those cells in a rather unusual way. Give it a go:

```py
# adjust max_row to your liking
# note that row and column indices in openpyxl are 1-based
for row in ws.iter_rows(min_row=3, min_col=1, max_row=3, max_col=26):
    j = 0    
    for cell in row:
        try:
            cell.value = a[j]
        except: # if the type of a[j] is actually not a string or any other acceptable datatype
            cell.value = str(a[j])

        j += 1
```

Comment: Catching an error without type is widely considered an antipattern (see [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10594113/bad-idea-to-catch-all-exceptions-in-python)). You would be better off specifying `except ValueError:` instead of `except:`.