# Redirected more times than rediection_limit allows - python/Django

Tags: python, django

I am trying to check if a URL is valid URL by doing this:

```
def check_urlstatus(url):
    h = httplib2.Http()
    try:
       resp = h.request("http://" + url, 'HEAD')        
       if int(resp[0]['status']) < 400:
           return 'ok'
       else:
           return 'bad'
    except (httplib2.ServerNotFoundError, UnicodeError, httplib2.RelativeURIError):
       return 'bad'
```

But some URLs dont seem to pass even if they are valid. e.g. this one: www.healthpolicyjrnl.com

I am getting the error:

```
Redirected more times than rediection_limit allows.
```

how can I catch this error? i would return `bad` for this.

second question is:
am I missing any other potential Error which I should catch in `except`?

Comment: see this [catching ANY exception](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4990718/python-about-catching-any-exception)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can see how this exception is raised in the [`httplib2` source](http://httplib2.googlecode.com/hg/python2/httplib2/__init__.py) and the custom `RedirectLimit` exception. So to catch it:

```
from httplib2 import RedirectLimit

try:
   ...
except (RedirectLimit, httplib2.ServerNotFoundError, UnicodeError, httplib2.RelativeURIError):
   return 'bad'
```

Comment: is it also possible to count the redirection?