# Python: Error Handling

Tags: macos, python-2.7, error-handling

I've got a program that gets some python code from the user and executes it. The problem is that if an error occurs, an error is raised.

Is there a way to catch if an error occurred, and if it has, just print it instead of raise it?

I want to really know the whole message that's raised, if that's possible.

I'm using python 2.7.9 on osx Yosemite.

Comment: https://wiki.python.org/moin/HandlingExceptions

Comment: possible duplicate of [Python: about catching ANY exception](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4990718/python-about-catching-any-exception)

Comment: That works! Try putting that in an answer!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It's as simple as

```
try:
    run_my_code()
except:
    print "Exception caught"
```

You can even print the exception details:

```
try:
    run_my_code()
except Exception as e:
    print "Exception message: " + e.message
```

For the most part, you will not want to catch all Exceptions - you should identify which exceptions are to be thrown and handle those individually. However if your intent is to prevent the program from exiting and/or print all exceptions, then catching all exceptions as fine.

Comment: But I was looking at the definitions of the classes of errors, and not all of them were defined as `class ErrorName(Exception):`. Does then exception include these ones?

Comment: Yes, because all the exceptions you want to catch are subclasses of Exception. It may not be a direct subclass, but a subclass of a subclass of Exception.