# Django Import - Export: IntegrittyError when trying to insert duplicate record in field(s) with unique or unique_together constraints

Tags: python, django, django-import-export

**Update**

I have filed a [feature request](https://github.com/django-import-export/django-import-export/issues/382). The idea is to `pass` on the `IntegrittyError` produced by the database when `unique` or `unique_together` reject a record that already exists in the database.

---

I have the following model:

```
class Compositions(models.Model):
    composer_key = models.ForeignKey(
        Composer,
        )
    composition = models.CharField(
        max_length=383,
        )

    class Meta(object):
        unique_together = (('composer_key', 'composition'), )
```

Using django-import-export in the admin interface, **without providing an `id` for each entry in the csv file**,  ... if one pair of the csv file already exists, the procedure will be interrupted with an integrity error

```
duplicate key value violates unique constraint "data_compositions_composer_key_id_12f91ce7dbac16bf_uniq"
DETAIL:  Key (composer_key_id, composition)=(2, Star Wars) already exists.
```

The CSV file is the following:

```
id  composer_key    composition
        1           Hot Stuff
        2           Star Wars
```

[The idea](https://github.com/django-import-export/django-import-export/issues/382#issuecomment-170454385) was to use `skip_row` and implement it in the admin.

admin.py:

```
class CompositionsResource(resources.ModelResource):

    class Meta:
        model = Compositions
        skip_unchanged = True
        report_skipped = True


class CompositionsAdmin(ImportExportModelAdmin):
    resource_class = CompositionsResource


admin.site.register(Compositions, CompositionsAdmin)
```

This will not cure the problem, however, because `skip_row` expects an `id` in the csv file in order to check if each row is the same with the very specific database entry.

Considering that this control can be performed by the database when using `unique`(`_together`) would not it be effective to catch this error and then return `skip_row = True` or alternatively `pass` on this error?

Comment: The [default implementation](https://github.com/django-import-export/django-import-export/blob/633c8fc5689c7c460163de72b89b6f2af1d39c9a/import_export/resources.py#L262) seems quite functional and should work out of the box. Can you show your CSV? Maybe, the `pk` attribute is what differs?

Comment: @AlexMorozov I have updated my answer with the relevant csv data. I wonder if removing the ```unique_together``` will make any difference, since the implemetation is correct. I will give it a try after work.

Comment: Is your `id` column empty? If so, when checking for a duplicate, a module might fool himself, because the new object's pk is different than of that in database. So it tries to add another record, and yes, fails because of `unique_together` constraint. I'd recommend you not to remove the constraint, but first try to assign a permanent `id`s to your csv records. Either way, let me know how it went )

Comment: @AlexMorozov Thank you for helping out! I have added the id: With the ```auto_now``` field, only the date field is updated. Without it, **as in my example**, it works as expected. In my case, it is unrealistic to provide the ```id```: How can I make import_export ```pass``` on the integrity error raised?

Comment: @raratiru I read [the issue](https://github.com/django-import-export/django-import-export/issues/382) on github and I'm facing the same. Did you maybe find a solution/workaround ?

Comment: @Paolo Actually, I did write a script that does the job. I am posting it below, although it is written 'on the fly'.

Comment: @Paolo Checkout the most recent answer on this issue, it is overwhelmingly cool!

Comment: have you tried `exclude = ('id',)` ?

Comment: @shouldsee The idea is to not import the duplicate value but keep importing the next one without halting at the `IntegrittyError`. Excluding the `id` will not help in this particular case because the database raises this error if a duplicate entry exists in the column, even with another id.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Only one Change is need. And you can use django-import-export

**models.py**

```
    class Compositions(models.Model):
        composer_key = models.ForeignKey(
            Composer,
            )
        composition = models.CharField(
            max_length=383,
            unique=False
            )
        date_created = models.DateTimeField(default=timezone.now)

        class Meta(object):
            unique_together = (('composer_key','composition'),)
```

override save_instance with try. And ignore error when fail. 
**admin.py**

```
        class CompositionsResource(resources.ModelResource):

            class Meta:
                model = Compositions
                skip_unchanged = True
                report_skipped = True

            def save_instance(self, instance, using_transactions=True, dry_run=False):
                try:
                    super(CompositionsResource, self).save_instance(instance, using_transactions, dry_run)
                except IntegrityError:
                    pass

        class CompositionsAdmin(ImportExportModelAdmin):
            resource_class = CompositionsResource

        admin.site.register(Compositions, CompositionsAdmin)
```

and import this

```
from django.db import IntegrityError
```

Comment: [How to write an answer](https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-answer). 
Add more details to justify your answer.

Comment: Thank you, great answer. It would be better to call [the parent](https://github.com/django-import-export/django-import-export/blob/master/import_export/resources.py#L266) `save_instance` to be sure that you do not break something. Instead of `instance.save()` you may try `super().save_instance(self,instance, using_transactions=True, dry_run=False)` and if it works add it to the post. Like [the code here](https://github.com/django-import-export/django-import-export/issues/382#issuecomment-376867890).

Comment: usign super().save_instance(self,instance, using_transactions=True, dry_run=False) not work. see this https://django-import-export.readthedocs.io/en/latest/api_resources.html#import_export.resources.Resource.save_instance

Comment: Bear in mind that [general error catching](https://stackoverflow.com/a/4990739/2996101) should be avoided, and also you have a typo: it is not `self,instance`, it is `self.instance`. Except for those, there is an issue with this solution: if a dry run is on the go, it will not pass on saving the instance. This interferes with import-export core functioning. You have a good answer but it cannot be marked as a solution.

Comment: OK! What about calling `super()`? Why did not it work?

Comment: not save data to model from file. seems to save, but changes in the model are not

Comment: Can you try this code after making sure that it is `def save_instance(self.instance,...`(a dot, not a comma): `super().save_instance(self.instance, using_transactions, dry_run)`

Comment: its works     using super(CompositionsResource,self).save_instance(instance, using_transactions, dry_run)

Comment: Yes that is the proper way. We need to call [`super()`](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/576169/understanding-python-super-with-init-methods) using the defined variables (using_transactions, dry_run), without redefining those variables. Edit your post, because it is the solution now!

Comment: Thank you too! Just edit the first attribute in both `def` and `super()` to read `self.instance`.

Comment: super(CompositionsResource,self).save_instance(self.instance,using_transactions, dry_run) create and error: atribute errror 'Resource' object has no attribute 'instance'.      it  works without self.instance

Comment: OK, you are very right. I just saw the source. Then the comma between `self` and `instance` is not a typo. To justify that, you need a space between `self,` and `instance`.

Answer (score 5):

A note on the accepted answer: it will give the desired result, but will slam the disk usage and time with large files.

A more efficient approach I've been using (after spending a lot of time going through the docs) is to override `skip_row`, and use a set of tuples as a unique constraint as part of the class. I still override `save_instance` as the other answer suggests to handle IntegrityErrors that get through, of course.

Python `sets` don't create duplicate entries, so they seem appropriate for this kind of unique index.

```
class CompositionsResource(resources.ModelResource):
  set_unique = set()

  class Meta:
    model = Composers
    skip_unchanged = True
    report_skipped = True

  def before_import(self, dataset, using_transactions, dry_run, **kwargs):
    # Clear out anything that may be there from a dry_run,
    #  such as the admin mixin preview
    self.set_unique = set()

  def skip_row(self, instance, original):
    composer_key = instance.composer_key  # Could also use composer_key_id
    composition = instance.composition
    tuple_unique = (composer_key, composition)

    if tuple_unique in self.set_unique:
      return true
    else:
      self.set_unique.add(tuple_unique)
    return super(CompositionsResource, self).skip_row(instance, original)

    # save_instance override should still go here to pass on IntegrityError
```

This approach will at least cut down on duplicates encountered within the same dataset. I used it to deal with multiple flat files that were ~60000 lines each, but had lots of repetitive/nested foreign keys. This made that initial data import way faster.

Answer (score 1):

models.py:

```
class Compositions(models.Model):
    composer_key = models.ForeignKey(
        Composer,
        )
    composition = models.CharField(
        max_length=383,
        unique=False
        )
    date_created = models.DateTimeField(default=timezone.now)

    class Meta(object):
        unique_together = (('composer_key','composition'),)
```

This is a script I have written 'on the fly' for the above model in order to automatically discard duplicate entries. I have saved it to `./project_name/csv.py` and import it from shell when I fill the relevant columns of the file `duc.csv` with data. The columns should not contain headers. Only data.

```
$./manage.py shell
>>> from project_name import csv
```

csv.py:

```
from data.models import Composer, Compositions
import csv
import sys, traceback
from django.utils import timezone

filename = '/path/to/duc.csv'

with open(filename, newline='') as csvfile:
    all_lines = csv.reader(csvfile, delimiter=',', quotechar='"')
    for each_line in all_lines:
        print (each_line)
        try:
            instance = Compositions(
                id=None,
                date_created=timezone.now(),
                composer_key=Composer.objects.get(id=each_line[2]),
                composition=each_line[3]
            )
            instance.save()
            print ("Saved composition: {0}".format(each_line[3]))
        except:  // exception type must be inserted here
            exc_type, exc_value, exc_traceback = sys.exc_info()  //debugging mostly
            print (exc_value)
```